# Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail

Tags: jquery, cdn, google-ajax-libraries

What would be a good way to attempt to load [the hosted jQuery at Google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) (or other Google hosted libs), but load my copy of jQuery if the Google attempt fails?

I'm not saying Google is flaky. There are cases where the Google copy is blocked (apparently in Iran, for instance).

Would I set up a timer and check for the jQuery object?

What would be the danger of both copies coming through?

Not really looking for answers like "just use the Google one" or "just use your own." I understand those arguments. I also understand that the user is likely to have the Google version cached. I'm thinking about fallbacks for the cloud in general.

---

Edit: This part added...

Since Google suggests using google.load to load the ajax libraries, and it performs a callback when done, I'm wondering if that's the key to serializing this problem.

I know it sounds a bit crazy. I'm just trying to figure out if it can be done in a reliable way or not.

---

Update: jQuery now hosted on Microsoft's CDN.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn/

Answer (score 827, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
       window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>');
</script>
```

This should be in your page's `<head>` and any jQuery ready event handlers should be in the `<body>` to avoid errors (although it's not fool-proof!).

One more reason to **not** use Google-hosted **jQuery** is that in some countries, Google's domain name is banned.

Comment: Aren't javascript downloads blocking (synchronous) already? Seems to me the double-copy issue would therefore not be a problem.

Comment: Javascript downloads should be synchronous already, as Matt Sherman said.  Otherwise, many problems would occur if the page tried to execute an inline script that relied on a library that was only half downloaded, or a library extension was executed without the library fully downloaded and executed.
That's also one reason why Yahoo YSlow recomends placing javascript at the end of pages; so that it doesn't block the downloading of other page elements (including styles and images).  At the very least, the browser would have to delay execution to occur sequentially.

Comment: Small fix from a validator fanatic: The string '</' is not allowed in JavaScript, because it could be misinterpreted as the end of the script tag (SGML short tag notation). Do '<'+'/script>' instead. Cheers,

Comment: To test if jQuery was loaded, (!window.jQuery) works fine, and is shorted then the typeof check.

Answer (score 336):

The easiest and cleanest way to do this by far:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 76):

This seems to work for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// has the google object loaded?
if (window.google && window.google.load) {
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
} else {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://joecrawford.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"><\/script>');
}
window.onload = function() {
    $('#test').css({'border':'2px solid #f00'});
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test">hello jQuery</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The way it works is to use the `google` object that calling http://www.google.com/jsapi loads onto the `window` object. If that object is not present, we are assuming that access to Google is failing. If that is the case, we load a local copy using `document.write`. *(I'm using my own server in this case, please use your own for testing this).*

I also test for the presence of `window.google.load` - I could also do a `typeof` check to see that things are objects or functions as appropriate. But I think this does the trick.

Here's just the loading logic, since code highlighting seems to fail since I posted the whole HTML page I was testing:

```
if (window.google && window.google.load) {
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
} else {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://joecrawford.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"><\/script>');
}
```

Though I must say, I'm not sure that if this is a concern for your site visitors you should be fiddling with the [Google AJAX Libraries API](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) at all.

**Fun fact**: *I tried initially to use a try..catch block for this in various versions but could not find a combination that was as clean as this. I'd be interested to see other implementations of this idea, purely as an exercise.*

Comment: What is the advantage of using google.load in this situation, rather than loading ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js directly,  like Rony suggested? I guess loading it directly catches issues with removed libraries as well (what if Google stops serving JQuery 1.3.2). Furthermore, Rony's version notices network problems AFTER www.google.com/jsapi has been fetched, especially when jsapi has been loaded from cache? One might need to use the google.load callback to be sure (or maybe there's some return value to include the google.load in the if(..)).

Comment: If one is testing for the presence of Google.com, one could make a network call, or one could check for the presence of the "gatekeeper" object. What I'm doing is checking for the google object and its "load" function. If both of those fail, no google, and I need the local version. Rony's version actually ignores the www.google.com/jsapi URL entirely, so I'm not sure why you indicate that it will have been fetched.

Comment: In the end, all that's required is that the jquery library is loaded. Any Google library is not a requirement. In Rony's answer, one knows for sure if loading from Google (or the cache) succeeded. But in your check for "if (window.google && window.google.load)", the jquery library is still not loaded. The actual loading of the jquery library is not validated?

Comment: ah, I see how I caused the confusion. "Rony's version notices network problems AFTER www.google.com/jsapi has been fetched" should better read: "Your version does not notice network problems AFTER www.google.com/jsapi has been fetched".

Comment: We've recently switched to using Google as our jQuery host; if we get any bug reports from blocked users, I'll be using a variant of your answer to refactor our client code.  Good answer!

Answer (score 31):

If you have modernizr.js embedded on your site, you can use the built-in yepnope.js to load your scripts asynchronously - among others jQuery (with fallback).

```
Modernizr.load([{
    load : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'
},{
    test : window.jQuery,
    nope : 'path/to/local/jquery-1.7.2.min.js',
    both : ['myscript.js', 'another-script.js'],
    complete : function () {
        MyApp.init();
    }
}]);
```

This loads jQuery from the Google-cdn. Afterwards it's checked, if jQuery was loaded successfully. If not ("nope"), the local version is loaded. Also your personal scripts are loaded - the "both" indicates, that the load-process is iniated independently from the result of the test.

When all load-processes are complete, a function is executed, in the case 'MyApp.init'.

I personally prefer this way of asynchronous script loading. And as I rely on the feature-tests provided by modernizr when building a site, I have it embedded on the site anyway. So there's actually no overhead.

Answer (score 22):

There are some great solutions here, but I'll like to take it one step further regarding the local file.

In a scenario when Google does fail, it should load a local source but maybe a physical file on the server isn't necessarily the best option. I bring this up because I'm currently implementing the same solution, only I want to fall back to a local file that gets generated by a data source.

My reasons for this is that I want to have some piece of mind when it comes to keeping track of what I load from Google vs. what I have on the local server. If I want to change versions, I'll want to keep my local copy synced with what I'm trying to load from Google. In an environment where there are many developers, I think the best approach would be to automate this process so that all one would have to do is change a version number in a configuration file.

Here's my proposed solution that should work in theory:

- In an application configuration file, I'll store 3 things: absolute URL for the library, the URL for the JavaScript API, and the version number
- Write a class which gets the file contents of the library itself (gets the URL from app config), stores it in my datasource with the name and version number
- Write a handler which pulls my local file out of the db and caches the file until the version number changes.
- If it does change (in my app config), my class will pull the file contents based on the version number, save it as a new record in my datasource, then the handler will kick in and serve up the new version.

In theory, if my code is written properly, all I would need to do is change the version number in my app config then viola! You have a fallback solution which is automated, and you don't have to maintain physical files on your server.

What does everyone think? Maybe this is overkill, but it could be an elegant method of maintaining your AJAX libraries.

Acorn

Answer (score 19):

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
// or if ( ! window.jQuery)
// or if ( ! 'jQuery' in window)
// or if ( ! window.hasOwnProperty('jQuery'))    

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = '/libs/jquery.js';

  var scriptHook = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  scriptHook.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scriptHook);

}
```

After you attempt to include Google's copy from the CDN.

In HTML5, you don't need to set the `type` attribute.

You can also use...

```
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/libs/jquery.js"><\/script>');
```

Answer (score 11):

You might want to use your local file as a last resort.

Seems as of now jQuery's own CDN does not support https. If it did you then might want to load from there first.

So here's the sequence: 
Google CDN =>
Microsoft CDN =>
Your local copy.

```
<!-- load jQuery from Google's CDN -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- fallback to Microsoft's Ajax CDN -->
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script> 
<!-- fallback to local file -->
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="Assets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Conditionally load latest/legacy jQuery version and fallback:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/public/vendor/jquery-legacy/dist/jquery.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/public/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 5):

Because of the Google's banning problem I prefer to use Microsoft's cdn
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx

Answer (score 5):

- Step 1: Did jQuery fail to load? (check `jQuery` variable)

[How to check a not-defined variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript)

- Step 2: Dynamically import (the backup) javascript file

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**
This answer turned out to be wrong. Please see the comments for the real explanation.

---

Most of you question has been answered, but as for the final part:

> What would be the danger of both copies coming through?

None really.  You'd waste bandwidth, might add some milliseconds downloading a second useless copy, but there's not actual harm if they both come through.  You should, of course, avoid this using the techniques mentioned above.

Comment: Actually, loading jQuery twice can cause lots of problems, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731897/loading-jquery-twice-causes-an-error).

Comment: why don't you test it yourself and manually load the jquery library twice. then the answer will be revealed.

Comment: Why exactly is it so wrong? @ShadowCat7 can you be more specific about the problems it causes? The only problem I see explicitly identified in the question you linked is "clearing all previously loaded plugins." But that should not apply to loading the same jQuery file twice back-to-back, right? I ask because the other solutions here to local fallback are so convoluted, and document.write is maligned as [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27531116/673991) in some [places](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/52dn3x/chrome_is_intervening_against_documentwrite/?st=j3br3bhp&sh=9bb65589).

Answer (score 4):

For those people using ASP.NET MVC 5, add this code in your BundleConfig.cs to enable the CDN for jquery:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
Bundle jqueryBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");
jqueryBundle.CdnFallbackExpression = "window.jQuery";
bundles.Add(jqueryBundle);
```

Comment: What should we do if the CDN has **integrity** and **crossorigin** attributes, such as this one: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')) { ...
```

Or

```
if(!window.jQuery){
```

Will not works if cdn version not loaded, because browser will run through this condition and during it still downloading the rest of javascripts which needs jQuery and it returns error. Solution was to load scripts through that condition.

```
    <script src="http://WRONGPATH.code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--  WRONGPATH for test-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function loadCDN_or_local(){
    if(!window.jQuery){//jQuery not loaded, take a local copy of jQuery and then my scripts
      var scripts=['local_copy_jquery.js','my_javascripts.js'];
      for(var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++){
      scri=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
      scri.type='text/javascript';
      scri.src=scripts[i];
    }
  }
  else{// jQuery loaded can load my scripts
    var s=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
    s.type='text/javascript';
    s.src='my_javascripts.js';
  }
  }
  window.onload=function(){loadCDN_or_local();};
  </script>
```

Comment: I found one problem in testing scripts in Google Chrome - caching. So for local testing just replace src in else section with something like  s.src='my_javascripts.js'+'?'+Math.floor(Math.random()*10001);

Comment: *[Alex's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo/4825258#4825258) will not work if cdn version not loaded, because browser will run through this condition and during it still downloading the rest of javascripts which needs jquery and it returns error* -> [JavaScript files being downloaded will block the next piece of code from being ran so it's not an issue](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2008/07/22/non-blocking-scripts/).

Answer (score 2):

I consider that should escape the last < to \x3C in string. When the browser sees , it considers this to be the end of the script block (since the HTML parser has no idea about JavaScript, it can't distinguish between something that just appears in a string, and something that's actually meant to end the script element). So  appearing literally in JavaScript that's inside an HTML page will (in the best case) cause errors, and (in the worst case) be a huge security hole.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a Gist that should dynamically load jQuery if it isn't already loaded, and if the source fails, it proceeds onto fallbacks (stitched together from many answers): https://gist.github.com/tigerhawkvok/9673154

Please note I plan to keep the Gist updated but not this answer, for what it's worth!

```
/* See https://gist.github.com/tigerhawkvok/9673154 for the latest version */
function cascadeJQLoad(i) { // Use alternate CDNs where appropriate to load jQuery
    if (typeof(i) != "number") i = 0;
    // the actual paths to your jQuery CDNs
    var jq_paths = [
        "ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js",
        "ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"
    ];
    // Paths to your libraries that require jQuery
    var dependent_libraries = [
        "js/c.js"
    ];
    if (window.jQuery === undefined && i < jq_paths.length) {
        i++;
        loadJQ(jq_paths[i], i, dependent_libraries);
    }
    if (window.jQuery === undefined && i == jq_paths.length) {
        // jQuery failed to load
        // Insert your handler here
    }
}

/***
 * You shouldn't have to modify anything below here
 ***/

function loadJQ(jq_path, i, libs) { //load jQuery if it isn't already
    if (typeof(jq_path) == "undefined") return false;
    if (typeof(i) != "number") i = 1;
    var loadNextJQ = function() {
        var src = 'https:' == location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http';
        var script_url = src + '://' + jq_path;
        loadJS(script_url, function() {
            if (window.jQuery === undefined) cascadeJQLoad(i);
        });
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        if (window.jQuery === undefined) loadNextJQ();
        else {
            // Load libraries that rely on jQuery
            if (typeof(libs) == "object") {
                $.each(libs, function() {
                    loadJS(this.toString());
                });
            }
        }
    }
    if (i > 0) loadNextJQ();
}

function loadJS(src, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = src;
    s.async = true;
    s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
        var state = s.readyState;
        try {
            if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
                callback.done = true;
                callback();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // do nothing, no callback function passed
        }
    };
    s.onerror = function() {
        try {
            if (!callback.done) {
                callback.done = true;
                callback();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // do nothing, no callback function passed
        }
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}

/*
 * The part that actually calls above
 */

if (window.readyState) { //older microsoft browsers
    window.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
            cascadeJQLoad();
        }
    }
} else { //modern browsers
    cascadeJQLoad();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Google Hosted jQuery**

- If you care about older browsers, primarily versions of IE prior to IE9, this is the most widely compatible jQuery version

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- If you don’t care about oldIE, this one is smaller and faster:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Backup/Fallback Plan!**

- Either way, you should use a fallback to local just in case the Google CDN fails (unlikely) or is blocked in a location that your users access your site from (slightly more likely), like Iran or sometimes China.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>if (!window.jQuery) { document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>'); }
</script>
```

**Reference:** http://websitespeedoptimizations.com/ContentDeliveryNetworkPost.aspx

Comment: Note loading scripts over insecure protocols opens an XSS attack vector.

Answer (score 1):

Using Razor syntax in ASP.NET, this code provides fallback support and works with a virtual root:

```
@{var jQueryPath = Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js");}
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='@jQueryPath' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

Or make a helper ([helper overview](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/23/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper.aspx)):

```
@helper CdnScript(string script, string cdnPath, string test) {
    @Html.Raw("<script src=\"http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/" + cdnPath + "/" + script + "\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + test + " || document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src='" + Url.Content("~/Scripts/" + script) + "' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E\"));</script>")
}
```

and use it like this:

```
@CdnScript("jquery-1.7.1.min.js", "ajax/jQuery", "window.jQuery")
@CdnScript("jquery.validate.min.js", "ajax/jquery.validate/1.9", "jQuery.fn.validate")
```

Comment: I've never heart about Razor, but it looks like an obfuscator, except for that it makes the code longer rather than shorter (it's twice as long as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9400432/581205).

Comment: @maaartinus: That's not an apples-to-apples comparison. BenjaminRH's answer, which you refer to, is for a single CDN-hosted script. With the `CdnScript` helper, you need only one line of code *per script*. The more scripts you have, the bigger the payoff.

Comment: Sure... it was just a rant. However, I guess that's not the optimal way. If anything fails, I'd ignore CDN completely and switch to the fallback for all scripts. I'm not sure if this is doable as I don't know how the loading exactly works.

Comment: @maaartinus: Since each CDN script load can fail independently, you have to check each load separately. There is no reliable method of a single CDN check followed by loading all scripts from CDN vs. locally.

Comment: The case that worries me is a failure of the CDN site leading to wait times for many loads. So I'd like to have something like `try { for (Script s : ...) cdnLoad(s); } catch (...) { for (Script s : ...) ownLoad(s); }`. Translating this into a bunch of `if`s could be a nightmare.

Comment: @maaartinus: That approach works if scripts are designed to be multiply loaded. Otherwise, if you have scripts A, B, and C, and A and B load from the CDN, but C fails, you would get a load sequence of {A, B, A, B, C}, with the first two loaded from CDN and the last three loaded from the web server. It seems like you need a g`tryCdn` variable initially set to true. Then each `cdnLoad` method would try the CDN first only if `tryCdn` is still true, and set it to false if a CDN load fails.

Comment: This makes sense! Additionally, after a couple of failures, which my server sees, I would let it avoid CDN for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Although writing `document.write("<script></script>")` seems easier for jQuery backoff, Chrome gives validation error on that case. So I prefer breaking "script" word. So it becomes safer like above.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
   window.jqFallback = true;
   document.write("<scr"+"ipt src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></scr"+"ipt>");
} </script>
```

For long term issues, it would be better to log JQuery fallbacks. In the code above, if first CDN is not available JQuery is loaded from another CDN. But you could want to know that erroneous CDN and remove it permanently. (this case is very exceptional case) Also it is better to log fallback issues. So you can send erroneous cases with AJAX. Because of JQuery isn't defined, you should use vanilla javascript for AJAX request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined' || window.jqFallback == true) {
        // XMLHttpRequest for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        // ActiveXObject for IE6, IE5
        var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        var url = window.jqFallback == true ? "/yourUrl/" : "/yourUrl2/";
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The inability to load the resource from an external data store beyond your control is difficult.  Looking for missing functions is totally fallacious as a means to avoid suffering a timeout, as described herein:
http://www.tech-101.com/support/topic/4499-issues-using-a-cdn/

Comment: The link above is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all public CDNs are pretty reliably. However, if you are worried about blocked google domain, then you can simply fallback to an alternative [jQuery CDN](https://pagecdn.com/lib/jquery). **However, in such a case, you may prefer to do it opposite way** and use some other CDN as your preferred option and fallback to Google CDN to avoid failed requests and waiting time:

```
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another fallback that replaces **ajax.googleapis.com** with **cdnjs.cloudflare.com**:

```
(function (doc, $)
{
    'use strict';

    if (typeof $ === 'undefined')
    {
        var script = doc.querySelector('script[src*="jquery.min.js"]'),
            src = script.src.replace('ajax.googleapis.com', 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com');

        script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
        doc.write('<script src="' + src + '"></script>');
    }
})(document, window.jQuery || window.Zepto);
```

- You can stick to a jQuery version by specifying it in the string
- Perfect for Asset Management that doesn't work with HTML snips
- Tested in the wild - works perfect for users from China

Comment: Could you elaborate on the following statement: "You don't have to care about the jQuery version"?

Comment: The version is part of the URL that is not goint to be touched by this approach... jquery/3.x.x/jquery.min.js

Comment: Does that have the potential to cause breakage when jQuery revs to version 4 and introduces backwards incompatible changes?

Comment: -1 because that will cause breakage if jQuery introduces breaking changes that your scripts won't support yet unless the version is specified.

Comment: @lookaji I think you don't understand the fallback. It does replace the domain where it is hosted and NOT touch the filename / version at all.

Comment: Sorry but I did not read your comment about keeping the version part untouched. Let me edit it so I can withdraw the -1 as I find (and apparently not only me judging by others too) your answer it a bit confusing. The fallback mechanism is to me obviously clear, btw :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

But also there are libraries you can use to setup **several** possible fallbacks for your scripts and optimize the loading process:

- basket.js
- RequireJS
- yepnope

Examples:

**basket.js**
I think the best variant for now. Will cach your script in the localStorage, that will speed up next loadings. The simplest call:

```
basket.require({ url: '/path/to/jquery.js' });
```

This will return a promise and you can do next call on error, or load dependencies on success:

```
basket
    .require({ url: '/path/to/jquery.js' })
    .then(function () {
        // Success
    }, function (error) {
        // There was an error fetching the script
        // Try to load jquery from the next cdn
    });
```

**RequireJS**

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min',
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'js/jquery-2.0.0.min'
        ]
    }
});

//Later
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
});
```

**yepnope**

```
yepnope([{
  load: 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js',
  complete: function () {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
      yepnope('js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js');
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to use a personal copy.  Here is my full belt and braces script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <!-- EMBED JQUERY USING GOOGLE APIs -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- IF THAT FAILS EMBED JQUERY USING CLOUDFLARE CDN -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
        </script>

        <!-- IF THAT FAILS ************* HOW??? *********** EMBED JQUERY FROM MICROSOFT -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"><\/script>');
        </script>

        <!-- IF THAT FAILS ************* WOW!!! *********** EMBED JQUERY FROM JQUERY.COM -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"><\/script>');
        </script>

        <!-- IF THAT FAILS ************* LET'S STOP!!! *********** EMBED JQUERY FROM PERSONAL COPY -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    </body>
</html>
```