# Is there a way to measure loaded content of page and show percentage of it?

Tags: javascript

I mean page preloaders where you see percentage of loaded page. Is it just fakened or is it truly a size of just loaded page related to whole page size? Is it possible to measure it with javascript? How developers make it? Here's example which seems to be kinda http://www.ultranoir.com/en/#!/home/

Comment: `(filesloaded / totalfilestoload) * 100`

Comment: that's simple math, but not the answer for what I'm asking for ;) I'm asking for possibilities to measure that- in your case filesloaded and totalfilesloaded

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0600__MS-JScript/FilesCount.htm for finding total files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293367/how-to-detect-if-javascript-files-are-loaded for how many loaded

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [jPreLoader jQuery plugin](http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/)

Using it is very simple :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').jpreLoader();
});
```

Comment: No jQuery tag present.

Answer (score 1):

Most websites are faking it. I was also searching sometime ago and only found solution like this plugin:
see in action here http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jpreLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').jpreLoader();
    });
// ]]></script>
```

also check out this solution, it's probably the closest to the real thing:
http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/progress.htm