# Loading javascript files in js files. Which is best way to check whether all files are loaded or not?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, loading

I have a array where i have specified the files i need to load in javascript before calling specific script. Lets call those particular lines of code as `myscript`.

I did as follows

```
var fileNamesArray = new Array();
    fileNamesArray.push("abc.js");
    fileNamesArray.push("pqr.js");
    fileNamesArray.push("xyz.js");
    fileNamesArray.push("klm.js");

    var totalFiles = jQuery(fileNamesArray).length;
    var tempCount = 0;

    jQuery.each(fileNamesArray, function(key, value) {
        jQuery.getScript(value, function() {
            tempCount++;
        });
    });
```

to check whether all files are being loaded or not, i done following thing but doesn't seems to be effective

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (tempCount == totalFiles) {
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            return;
        }
    }, 10);
```

i have implemented these in object oriented javascript as follows

```
function Loader() {

    this.jQuery = null;

    // check for specifically jQuery 1.8.2+, if not, load it

    if (jQuery == undefined) {
        jQuery.getScript(
                "/Common/javascript/jquery/map/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.js",
                function() {
                    this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
                });
    } else {
        var jQueryVersion = $.fn.jquery;

        jQueryVersion = parseInt(jQueryVersion.split('.').join(""));

        if (182 > jQueryVersion) {
            jQuery.getScript(
                    "/Common/javascript/jquery/map/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.js",
                    function() {
                        this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
                    });
        }
    }
}

Loader.prototype.LoadAllFile = function() {
//here i am loading all files
}

Loader.prototype.bindMap = function(options) {
this.LoadAllFile();
//execute the script after loading the files... which we called as myscript
}
```

i am loading more than 12-14 js files via ajax.

if you observe `Loader.prototype.bindMap`, i am loading all the files first and then executing the script.

But it seems that `myscript` the script start executing before all files being loaded.

what are the better ways to execute the script only after all js files are loaded.

Comment: You might find your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293367/how-to-detect-if-javascript-files-are-loaded

Comment: Sounds like you should consider a module loader eg `requirejs` or `curl`

Comment: @r3mus i can not load files in head section or body section using `<script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>`. need to load all files in JS only.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's .load() http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

```
$('script').load(function () { });
```

Comment: This method is deprecated as of Jquery1.8. The "on" method must be used instead

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation on [Jquery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) , it is a shorthand for Jquery.ajax. By default this in async call. You might want to change it to do a synchronous call. 
To set this property, you can refer to [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)

So instead of doing a setInterval, you can just loop in your array and do a Jquery.getScript.