# Using jQuery / javascript How to check if JS file ( SP.JS) is already called in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, document-ready

I want to check if a particular JS file is already loaded in document.ready.

Something like this:

```
if(file already called/loaded) { // my code }
else {//some other code}
```

The JS File is not any plugin.

Its basically a JS file related to SharePoint like Sp.JS.

We just know the file name.

[Update - Added the code ]

I have added the below code and it throws an error in console : SP.Runtime.js is already loaded.

If I remove the loading of SP.Runtime.js my code doesnt work in some pages where Runtime.Js is not loaded by default.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "init.js",
    function() {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function() {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
            function() {
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js",
                    function() {
                        context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                       // My custom function //

                    });
            });
    });
    });
});
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: `if($("script[src='SCRIPT_URL']").length) { //do stuffs }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293367/how-to-detect-if-javascript-files-are-loaded

Visit this

Comment: @user2598808 still no answer? if yes please mark it.

Comment: I can't belive this question has not an answer yet, even though the SharePoint JavaScript libraries dont need to be forced to load, the only requirement is to load the code at the right moment as stated in both answers below. I think a moderator should take a look at this.

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint JavaScript Library, in particular [SP.SOD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410742(v=office.14).aspx) namespace contains methods for loading/ensuring JavaScript files.

1. [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx) - executes the specified
   function if the file containing it is loaded, for example:

   ```
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunc, "SP.js");

   function myfunc()
   {
   }
   ```

   In that case `myfunc` will be invoked **after** sp.js file is loaded
2. [SP.SOD.executeFunc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx) - ensures that the specified file that
   contains the specified function is loaded and then runs the
   specified callback function, for example:

   ```
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', 
    function (){
        //your code goes here...
    });
   ```

   The behavior is similar to previous example but the main difference
   that this function also supports *load on demand* scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the response Vadim. I have modified the code based on your suggestions. I am still getting an error. That is what am trying to fix. To check if SP.Runtime.Js is already loaded and load it based on that. Any suggestions? Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to ensure that specific native JS files of SharePoint are loaded before executing your code then Vadim's answer is all what you need, however if you require to ensure the loading of all page elements including all JS files then you should use `window.onload`.

Please take a look at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) where people discuss about the differences between `windows.onload` and `$(document).ready()`.

[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

UPDATE:
In case you are using your code in any page within SharePoint then you don't need to force the loading of native JS files, you only need to execute your code at the right moment of the page load process.
Try using `$(window).load` or `window.onload` instead of `$(document).ready`, by example:

`$(window).load(function(){
     SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function (){
           context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
          //your code goes here...
     });
});`

Comment: Thanks for the response Issac. I have modified the code based on your suggestions. I have updated my question with the latest code. I am still getting an error. Any suggestions? Thank You.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out! in IE, it was working just fine with (document).ready but not with Chrome. (window).load fixed this problem :)