# Best practice to include src url or download?

Tags: jquery, download, cdn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Linking vs. Download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093566/jquery-linking-vs-download)

What is the best practice?

1. Do I include the google api url for jquery or
2. Do I download the jquery file on my server and use it?

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer to give path of google. for more detailed answer you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn)

- The google api servers are distributed across the world instead of my single server location: Closer servers usually means faster response times for the visitor.
- Many people choose to have JQuery hosted on Google, so when a visitor comes to my site they may already have the JQuery script in their local cache. Pre-cached content usually means faster load times for the visitor.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to include the google link.

But If for some reason you will develop on a machine without internet access, you should download it on your server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on local then

```
download a copy and use it.
```

if on server then

```
take a cdn link
```

Reason behind it, it process the page faster.

Comment: +1 because just like my suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Pros of having Google host jQuery for you:

- Some of your users may already have the script in their caches, as other Web sites may use the same URL to load the same code.
- Otherwise, Google's server may be geographically closer and therefore latency could be lower.

Cons of having Google host jQuery for you:

- Connecting to ajax.googleapis.com might require an additional DNS request, increasing load time.
- For intranet sites, latency will be higher than that of connecting to a server on the same local network.
- If Google is down (or your site is an intranet site and your Internet connection is down), the script might not load at all.

  - If you load the script at the top of a page, the page might be unreadable until the connection to Google times out.
  - Some employers' restrictive firewalls [block all connections to Google, including those to Google APIs.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/employer-blocks-jquery-from-google-doh)
- If Google gets hacked, they could deliver malicious JavaScript that impacts your site. Malicious code would have access to anything your users can get to through your site.
- Google would know your users' IP addresses, which may be a privacy concern.

As for Stack Overflow itself, they do use Google's service despite all the disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Download jQuery To Your Server. How it Helps:

1. Can Work Offline.
2. The Documents Will Load Faster.

Answer (score 0):

according to him and  including me ..:) .. i would go for the 1 option....include the googleapi url...

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to have a fallback in case the CDN  is down :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
// Fallback
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

That comes from HTML5 Boilerplate.