# validate and unobtrusive js from CDN - fallback to local copy

Tags: javascript, validation, cdn, unobtrusive-javascript

Really sorry to do this, I've asked this  before, but didnt get an answer i wanted, and for some reason I can't add a bounty to the question! - the link is nowhere to be seen!

[How to load local script files as fallback in cases where CDN are blocked/unavailable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/using-local-script-files-instead-of-cdn-in-cases-where-they-are-blocked)

Basically i need to know how to fall back onto my local files in the case that the cdn for:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js

are blocked too. I know how to do it for jquery now.