# Failover loading of .js from sequence of servers?

Tags: javascript, loading, failover

Let's imagine a web page page needing to load a javascript file (i.e. `my.js`). Is it possible to organize the following fail-over loading sequence?

1. If server A is up, load `my.js` from server A.
2. Else, if server B is up, load `my.js` from server B.
3. Else, if server C is up, load `my.js` from server C.
4. ...

If yes, how to proceed? Thanks.

P.S.: I have just found [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/). Does anyone recommend it?

Comment: This does not sound like a programming question but a question for Active-Active Cluster environments.  You may want to try ServerFault.

Comment: @John no no, it is not about clustering, the servers are not necessarily part of the same cluster.

Comment: Look at [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/how-to-load-local-script-files-as-fallback-in-cases-where-cdn-are-blocked-unavail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this technique to allow a fallback if a CDN is down.
If your js file has some testable property like a global variable (I've called it marker), you can attempt to load the file from server A, test for the marker and if it is not found script another attempt.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server_A.tld/my.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if( !window.marker ) {
    document.write(
        '<script type="text\/javascript" src="http:\/\/server_B.tld\/my.js"><\/script>'
    );
}
</script>
```

Update
There is no danger that all the scripts will run using this technique. [John Resig explains this in a blog post.](http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/). Scripts can download in parallel and in any order but they *must* execute in order.

[Here is a fiddle that demonstrates](http://jsfiddle.net/HaNGR/2/)

Comment: Ok, but are we sure the second statement (i.e. document write) will be executed after the attempt to load from A has failed? In other words, are we sure this is strictly sequential? (sorry if the question sounds stupid, but I am not a javascript expert)

Comment: Is it frequent that a CDN goes down?

Comment: @cherouvim Not very likely but not impossible I guess.