# How to make the source(path) of MathJax.js environment dependent?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

How do I specify the following requirement in my html?

When the computer has access to Internet, the source of MathJax.js is https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js;

When it is offline, and the system is Linux, the source is `/MathJax/MathJax.js`; if the system is Windows, it is `/C:/MathJax/MathJax.js`. (It would be even better if I can use environment variable in the local path.)

Comment: I benefit from both Mark's and Nacho's answer. Thanks a lot. However the bounty cannot be divided, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put MathJax in a location relative to your static HTML file:

```
<script src="https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"></script>
<script>
if( !window.MathJax ) {
    document.write(
        '<script type="text\/javascript" src="../lib/MathJax.js"><\/script>'
    );
}
</script>
```

This way your implementation is independent of the OS.

Another option would be to set up the location according to your browser URL:

```
<script>
var url= location.protocol == 'http:'? 
         "https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js" :
         "../lib/MathJax.js";
document.write(
    '<script type="text\/javascript" src="' + url + '"><\/script>'
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

These other pages might provide you with some new approaches to a solution.

The first one demos how you might chain a list of url's together, and continue trying to load the next script if the previous one fails.

[Failover loading of .js from sequence of servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448449/failover-loading-of-js-from-sequence-of-servers)

You would need to add your logic around Windows vs Linux into that.

Here are some ideas around detecting if the web page is running offline:
[Detect that the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

If you could provide some more information about your application, I can probably come up with some better suggestions.  Is this an application users install on their local computer? How do these JS files get onto people's C:\? What is installed when the app installs? How does it run? Is a local server installed as well? Or are the html pages just run from the file system in the web browser?