# React onClick event is not firing on bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to log the user out when I click on the "logout" element located inside the dropdown menu.

but the onClick event is not firing when I click on that.

this is the code

```
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    ...

      <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-userdata dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >
                    <img src={user.avatar} className={"avatar"} alt={"user avatar"}
                        />
                    <div  className="dropdown-toggle" >{user.name}</div>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu bg-dark">
                            <li><a href={"#"} onClick={() => console.log("logout")}>Logout</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <span className="caret"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
    ...
      </nav>
```

there are no errors in console ,onClick work as intended when i add it outside the dropdown menu.

is there a way to make this work while using bootstrap dropdown menu?

Comment: check after remove href from <a> tag, like <a onClick={() => console.log("logout")}>

Comment: no luck.
it's not working even if I change it to a button, <li><button onClick={() => console.log("logout")}>Logout</button></li>

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue by manually toggling the 'show' class in dropdown menu

```
const [isDropdownOpen,setDropdown] = useState(false);
const logout = () => {
        dispatch(logoutUser());
    };

 <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    ...

       <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto" onClick={() => setDropdown(!isDropdownOpen)}>
            <li className="nav-userdata dropdown" >
                <img src={user.avatar} className={"avatar"} alt={"user avatar"}
                     title={"You must have a gravatar connected to display the avatar"}/>
                <div className={"dropdown-toggle"}>{user.name}</div>
                    <ul id={'dropdown-userdata'} className={classnames('dropdown-menu bg-dark dropdown-userdata', {'show': isDropdownOpen})}>
                        <li><a href={'#'} className='nav-link'  onClick={logout}>Logout</a></li>
                        <li><Link to={'/dashboard'} className={'nav-link'}>Dashboard</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                <span className="caret"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    ...
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

While function call closing the anchor tag without and after that only the onclick functionality will work. I think every thing is fine with your work but the arrow symbol is overriding the anchor tag closing. So just check it will work fine

Comment: I don't think that's the case here. onClick works if i place it outside the "dropdown-menu"

Answer (score 0):

```
 You need e.preventDefault() in the click handler.

It's firing but the default behavior of an anchor is to refresh the page, so 
it's just rerendering immediately.

<li><a  onClick={(e) => this.logout(e)}>Logout</a></li>

logout =(e) =>{
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('logout')
 }
```

try something like this,may it work

Comment: not working. behavior is the same regardless of the element I use (a, button . .....). but it's working if I place onClick outside the "dropdown-menu"

Comment: whats your bootstrap version?

Comment: i think you have not loaded js file for the bootstrap

Comment: bootstrap 4.3.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980046/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-in-react/50980203
check this link

Comment: bootstrap is loaded properly. expand and collaps on dropdown menu is working.