# Bootstrap dropdown in react is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is my code, everything is fine but when I click on the dropdown button, it shows a blank option like there is no option available to show in the dropdown menu.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { DropdownButton, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";

const  App=()=> {

  const [cities, setCities] = useState(["agra", "delhi"])

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2 className="text-center">Welcome to Nivaran</h2>

        <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Choose State">
          {cities.map(city => {
            <Dropdown.Item href="#">{city}</Dropdown.Item>
          })}
        </DropdownButton>

      </div>
    );
  }


export default App;
```

Update:-

Answer-
Actually, I am knew to react, I was unaware of the return statement that I was missing

```js
{cities.map((city) => {
          return <Dropdown.Item href="#">{city}</Dropdown.Item>;
        })}
```

Comment: [@deepak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13767516/deepak-kumar) Once go through this blog contains 5 answers hope it works for you :) [Blog Link](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/299985)

Comment: i have mention answer below  it will work

Comment: thank you Sumit Gajera, but my case is different, there is no problem with drop-down because when I use dropdown without map, it works, but it does not work with map

Comment: Check this for more [Bootstrap Dropdown - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980046/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-in-react/54188034)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the return jsx while map the cities

```
 {cities.map((city) => {
     return <Dropdown.Item href="#">{city}</Dropdown.Item>;
  })}
```

Or you can check without return like below

```
 {cities.map(city => 
     <Dropdown.Item href="#">{city}</Dropdown.Item>
 )}
```

I hope it will work for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, actually, I am knew to react, I was unaware of return statement

Comment: You can also map without return statement.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed return inside the dropdown now it will work

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { DropdownButton, Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';

const App = () => {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState(['agra', 'delhi']);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2 className="text-center">Welcome to Nivaran</h2>

      <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Choose State">
        {cities.map((city) => {
          return <Dropdown.Item href="#">{city}</Dropdown.Item>;
        })}
      </DropdownButton>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```