# Bootstrap not working with React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to apply Bootstrap attributes to my `<span>` and `<button>`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've searched this question here in stackoverflow, but all of the suggestions say to change class to className. I've done this but I'm still unable to see my styles change.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import Counter from './components/counter';

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

counter.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count: 0
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span className="badge badge-primary m-2">
                    {this.formatCount()}
                </span>
                <button className="btn btn-secondaty btn- 
sm">Increment</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    formatCount() {
        const { count } = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }
} 

export default Counter;
```

Any insight into this problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you imported the CSS? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985246/885626

Comment: I have now. It's working. Thanks for the suggestion Ric!

Answer (score 11):

In bootstrap v5 it's changed to `"bg-primary"` and `"bg-secondary"` etc instead, so try `className="badge bg-primary m-2"`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have already installed Bootstrap, then add this `import` statement to your code:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem. Somehow I find that bootstrap version causing trouble to me!

So I **uninstalled** current version then **installed** an specific version.

```
npm remove bootstrap

npm install bootstrap@4.6.0
```

Then import necessary bootstrap script in **App.js** file.

```
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

or

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of bootstrap, there are few changes in the badge class.

According to Bootstrap v5.0 and above, use the following code for the Badge class.

render() {
return (

{this.formatCount()}
Increment

);

Answer (score 0):

`npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`

Install this dependency and all style will be work

Answer (score -1):

Replace class name with className="badge bg-primary m-2",

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/badge/

Comment: Please do not repeat the solution of existing answers to say thanks for them. Instead wait until you have the voting privilege, that is the proper way. Please delete this post now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).