# Does React-Bootstrap need both npm install bootstrap and bootstrap CDN or just one of them?

Tags: reactjs, npm, cdn, react-bootstrap

I've seen two kinds of tutorials for React-Bootstrap.

Sometimes the tutorials show to install both **React-Bootstrap** and **Bootstrap** with `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap` and then add the CDN link for Bootstrap in the **index.html**.

Then in other tutorials, it's just `npm install react-bootstrap` + CDN for Bootstrap in **index.html**

---

For example, Youtuber called Brice Ayres has this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOK9l5uP06U ,

where he makes a website with React, React-Bootstrap, React-Router and Styled-Components.

On the video, he installs both **React-Bootstrap** and **Bootstrap**, and then adds the CDN link.

---

On the React-Bootstrap homepage https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction, there's a text like this:

> If you plan on customizing the Bootstrap Sass files, or don't want to
>   use a CDN for the stylesheet, it may be helpful to install vanilla
>   Bootstrap as well.

So I believe that it's up to the programmer to either choose to install Bootstrap with NPM or use a CDN link. Having both of them sounds a bit wierd in this.

Or have I misunderstood the use-case of the NPM Bootstrap package? Because I've thought that it's the same stylesheet as the CDN stylesheet?

---

Long story short: Is it enough to install just react-bootstrap and then add the CDN?

Comment: just install the module, no need for the cdn. It could just lead to override of styling, Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037657/how-to-include-bootstrap-css-and-js-in-reactjs-app

Comment: But isn't CDN better because it caches itself to user's browser? It has faster loading time with that.

Comment: It is. It actually depends on the requirement. For me the module gives me fully control of what i want.

Comment: Well I am a noob/rookie in Web Dev so I don't care about customizing all the little things in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Bootstrap.css file because its not part of the `reactstrap` packages...

for this you need either

1. `npm install bootstrap` and refer to the css file via an
   `import` statement in your JS
2. add the CDN `<link href=' ../>` inside the index.html file...

For deploying your web project to live, CDN will give a greater coverage for global audiences so you have to weigh the `CDN` vs `local package` value proposition based on your unique factors