# Unable to display bootstrap panels in react js

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to display these bootstrap panels from here
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_panels.asp : 
*the header and footer one*.

I have installed bootstrap in my project. And I can see the **Button** is working fine, but **panels** are not coming up.

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <Button href="#">Link</Button>
      </center>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the output but it *does not display the panels* properly:

[image]

Comment: I think, You missed to import the bootstrap's css in your application.

Comment: I think you are using bootstrap version 4 and if so you need to use ```card``` and not panel and working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-tqdxf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985246/13146189 i did all the stepf from this ans, idk why it still isnt coming

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yea let me try using cards

Comment: @ManirajMurugan i have no idea how you are getting the output and I am not

Comment: @user1997, Can you create a codesandbox reproducing your issue as like I did?? If you try the code which I have provided then it should work if you use bootstrap 4..

Comment: pls can you tell me how to add bootstrap to pmy react js, it soent seem to be working, even after putting using npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step.1**: [install bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/#package-managers)

```
npm install bootstrap
```

**Step.2**: [include bootstarp CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985246/2873538)

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Also, Note that in your code, you are using `class` instead of `className`. Though, [it might work but with warnings](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html#changes-in-detail). Check how to do [styling in reactjs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html).

**Example:**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-header">Card Header</div>
      <div className="card-body">Card Body</div>
      <div className="card-footer text-muted">Card Footer</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-dew-sl3ie?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I just need bootsstrap only for styling