# Bootstrap CSS fallback not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fallback

I'm working on a boilerplate with 3 fallbacks: jQuery, Bootstrap.js and Bootstrap.css. The first 2 are working fine, but I can't make the css fallback work properly (I'm using this reference: [Should I use Bootstrap from CDN or make a copy on my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192897/should-i-use-bootstrap-from-cdn-or-make-a-copy-on-my-server))

Here's the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <title></title>
      <meta name="description" content="" />
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/{{BOOTSTRAP_VERSION}}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="{{BOOTSTRAP_SRI_HASH}}" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-{{JQUERY_VERSION}}.min.js" integrity="{{JQUERY_SRI_HASH}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/{{BOOTSTRAP_VERSION}}/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="{{BOOTSTRAP_SRI_HASH}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="hidden" id="bootstrapCssTest"></div>
  <script>
    if (typeof($.fn.modal) === 'undefined') {
        document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        if ($('#bootstrapCssTest').is('visible')) {
            $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
        }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/bundle.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: your links to the Bootstrap CDN are not correct, why do you have {{BOOTSTRAP_VERSION}} and jquery version like that?

Comment: Its fine, they are no supposed to work in this case. I want then to fail to get the fallback.

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped the selector. You need `:visible`, not `visible`

```
$(function() {
  if ($('#bootstrapCssTest').is(':visible')) {
    $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
  }
})
```