# Should i link bootstrap or install locally?

Tags: performance, installation, bootstrap-4

I'm making a personal portfolio website and decided to use Bootstrap 4. Should I add the bootstrap js and CSS files and link from my server, or is linking pretty reliable?

Comment: Use cdn link (e.g. maxcdn) and then local server as a fall back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap CDN is reliable, and I often prefer using CDN. There are couple of good insights about this topic. You can see here [Stackoverflow Discussion/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26198380/700530)