# WordPress fallback for Bootstrap's CDN without relying on JavaScript?

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, cdn

Developing a theme for WordPress using Bootstrap 4 I'm familiar with the suggested approach of coding a `<div>`:

```
<div id="bootstrapCssTest" class="hidden"></div>
```

and checking it with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($('#bootstrapCssTest').is(':visible') === true) {
        $('<link href="/localcopy/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').appendTo('head');
    }
</script>
```

reference: "[How to load local copy of bootstrap css when the cdn server is down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141532/how-to-load-local-copy-of-bootstrap-css-when-the-cdn-server-is-down)" but I would like a way to test the CSS without JavaScript and  enqueue Bootstrap's CSS depending on if the CDN is found. Upon research I read that `fopen` may not be allowed always on the server level so I opted for [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), the code:

```
function bootstrap_css() {
    $bootstrap_cdn   = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    $cdn_check       =  @get_headers($bootstrap_cdn);

    if ($cdn_check[0] === "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") :
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',$bootstrap_cdn,array(),'4.2.1');

        function add_cross_origin($html,$handle) {
            if ('bootstrap' === $handle) {
                return str_replace("media='all'","media='all' integrity='sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS' crossorigin='anonymous'",$html);
            }
                return $html;
            }
        add_filter('style_loader_tag','add_cross_origin',10,2);
    else :
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',get_site_url() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',false,'4.2.1');
    endif;
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','bootstrap_css');
```

Is there a better approach to checking wether the Bootstrap CSS CDN is available that doesn't use JavaScript to test? Should I be checking anything beyond the "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"? Would `cURL` be better to use then `get_headers`?

Comment: Mind the status "304 - found"  thats the way a cdn should work

Comment: @johnSmith Why not write an answer explaining what you're referring to? I would upvote it and I think others would too

Comment: well because it´s a comment, i will add another one: if your server successfull tested  cdn, it doesn´t mean that when the client requests it is available for client as well, thats why a client-side check makes more sense to me. If you dont want to rely on cdn you could always use your local copy

Comment: If you want to do that on client side, doing it on service worker would feel like better approach. But I'm not sure about doing it on server. Just because server got success message, doesn't mean that client can download it (although it's a very rare case).

Comment: So how should I conditionalize for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first time the php script tries accessing the CSS file, the server returns a status code 304. The easiest implementation to check for this would be the following:

```
function bootstrap_css() {
$bootstrap_cdn   = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';
$cdn_check       =  @get_headers($bootstrap_cdn);

if (strpos($cdn_check[0], "200") !== false || strpos($cdn_check[0], "304") !== false) :
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',$bootstrap_cdn,array(),'4.2.1');

function add_cross_origin($html,$handle) {
    if ('bootstrap' === $handle) {
        return str_replace("media='all'","media='all' integrity='sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS' crossorigin='anonymous'",$html);
    }
        return $html;
    }
add_filter('style_loader_tag','add_cross_origin',10,2);
    else :
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',get_site_url() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',false,'4.2.1');
    endif;
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','bootstrap_css');
```