# What is the standard way to add javascript libraries to my project?

Tags: javascript, cdn

I am working on a javascript project and I am using cytoscape.js and bootstrap.js. Should I include the library files in my project, or use the files from their repository,using a link to their github repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safer to use an own saved version.

- You won't depend other sites.
- Your sites won't depend other site's network connectivity.
- You don't have to care about version upgrades.

On the other hand

- you have to care about potential bugs, security issues yourself. Follow the related channels, and fix manually or upgrade.
- this can be more bandwidth consuming. (minified versions/compression/client side cacheing can help.)

Answer (score 1):

In production mode you should use cdn for minified version of assets (js, images, etc.).
The main benefit of using cdn - caching

Answer (score 0):

This depends - for development the best practice is to host the files yourself, or link to fixed-version numbers (ie: jQuery 1.9.1). This means that you're not going to face an issue when the library is updated.

Common courtesy would be to host the files yourself if it's a non-public project - whereas for open-source or community projects I would have no qualms with someone linking directly to the source file for one of my libraries.

Be warned, whilst this latter option might save you bandwidth, you lose control of your source files and so, if their hosting drops or they move the files, your project will break. Safest is to host them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bootstrap CDN instead.
http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDN and fallback to local files if CDN is not available. Described here: [How to load local script files as fallback in cases where CDN are blocked/unavailable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/how-to-load-local-script-files-as-fallback-in-cases-where-cdn-are-blocked-unavai/5531821#5531821)