# How i can download bootstrap-dialog.min.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Where can I download the file: `bootstrap-dialog.min.js`?

I arrived here:
https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/blob/master/examples/assets/bootstrap-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js

But not sure how I can download the file.

I just want to load it in locally.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/master/examples/assets/bootstrap-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js

this is the file.right click and save as...

Comment: Just use the CDN or download from CDN - http://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap3-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- copy/past file content locally:

  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/master/dist/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js
- clone repo locally:

  `git clone https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog.git`
- download npm package:

  `npm install bootstrap3-dialog`
- download bower package:

  `bower install bootstrap3-dialog`

Comment: file content no longer valid.  Please remove the link or replace with a valid one.

Comment: @Juniuz updated link

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use it, then I recommend making use of a CDN. For example, head over to cdnjs.com and you can find it there and add the reference to your page.

Direct Link: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap3-dialog

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.5/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.5/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You may also open the development/production js file directly on your browser and save it from there.

Or you can install NPM, then with NPM install Bower, with bower you can manage your assets much easier. For example, you can run `bower install bootstrap3-dialog` and this will take care of downloading everything for you. Then you pick whichever you wish to use "development" or "production" css/js files.

Comment: Thanks :) I thinked that is better to have it saved in local. Becouse if there is some problem in remote, i risk that website not work correctly. It is bad?

Comment: You can have CDN then fall back to local if CDN fails. Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/how-to-load-local-script-files-as-fallback-in-cases-where-cdn-are-blocked-unavai) to help you get started. CDN's normally perform much faster than serving the css/js yourself.

Comment: interesting. just i have some doubt. In header i have almost seven-eight of these files. Is normal / usual query more server one to one it?

Comment: If your web application is internet facing (meaning, users will access it from outside your network) then a CDN will normally perform better. CDNs  tend to have More servers, The bandwidth being used (you don't pay for), Geolocation to lower response time to users, Redundancy and optimized caching settings.