# jquery cdn had bad latency, how to solve

Tags: jquery, performance, low-latency

thx to insights @azure, I saw that there were some bad latency with code.jqery.
Am I first, Has anyone else had this bad latency with jquery cdn?

[image]

br

Comment: This is one to bring up with the people at jQuery CDN. There isn't really any way to answer your question here, and it's not really programming related per se.

Comment: Looking at the title and not the body of the question, it's solvable. There are ways to set up a "fallback script". Might be too broad at that point?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/how-to-load-local-script-files-as-fallback-in-cases-where-cdn-are-blocked-unavai) or [it's dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)

Comment: Thx @Terminus, all those fallbacks helps if the server failed to load (means response is something else than 200). In my case request was made and response was not finished after 2sec, because of that the test was aborted and resulted as failed. All those fallbacks if they do not implement some kind of timeouts would not work, or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: @MattFletcher well concerning programming: do not use unstable CDN, which instead to fail keeps connection open responding few bits every few seconds. Related to defensive programming, what would be the solution to be on the safe side, all those fallbacks to local file does not help in this case because response is on the way and that bring us to what would be best practices. Because of that I disagree with your comment ;) By the way, I have mention jquery.cdn because, this was not first time