# How to load <script> tag when Internet Connection exists?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this script for google maps:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{env.GOOGLE_API_KEY}}'></script>
```

and i want to load it in html file with javascript, only if i have internet connection.

I checked about the internet with **navigator.onLine** and I tried with below code to load the   script :

```
var api = '{{env.GOOGLE_API_KEY}}';    
       if (api && navigator.onLine){ 

     var head = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var jsapi = document.createElement("script");
    jsapi.type = "text/javascript";
    jsapi.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+api+""; 
    console.log(jsapi); 
    head.appendChild(jsapi);
    }
```

but not work.
Maybe it is slow to load the script.

Comment: How does it not work? The code seems fine...

Comment: Try to check every N seconds for online

Comment: Possible [duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/how-to-load-local-script-files-as-fallback-in-cases-where-cdn-are-blocked-unavai)
Because you can load the script from a remote place, and then fallback to a local place if the remote fails.