# How to stop jQuery loading twice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I've run into a problem. The framework I'm using (Symfony2) has support for third party bundles. The `CreateBundle` requires that you include some javascript on the page. To do this, you call:

```
    {% render(controller("cmf_create.jsloader.controller:includeJSFilesAction")) %}
```

This is where the problem arises. That template includes jquery. I have another bundle which also includes jquery. When the second jquery script loads, it seems to overwrite the first one, breaking createJS.

How can I make it so that one instance of jQuery is used regardless of how many times it is included in the document?

**Edit**

I don't have control over the sources as both are rendered as templates from another bundle. How can I resolve the conflicts without modifying the sources of either include?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13350482/1090068

Answer (score 0):

In theory, there shouldn't be a problem try to load a library twice (just a warning message). Is it possible that the bundles use diffenrent versions of JQuery?