# Custom Controls and Web Resources (scripts)

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am developing a Server Custom Control (.NET), a "DatePicker" with the jQueryUI Plugin.
So, i have the next script, that is loaded as a webResource:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#" + ctrlInput).datepicker({
        maxDate: MaxDate,
        minDate: MinDate
    });
});
```

As you can see, i have javascript variables, so, for loading the script and the variables, i do the next:

**C#**

```
        string javascriptVariables = String.Format(
            "var MinDate = '{0}'; var MaxDate = '{1}'; var ctrlInput = '{2}';",
            MinDate ?? DateTime.MinValue.ToShortDateString(), 
            MaxDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue.ToShortDateString(),
            _textBox.ClientID
        );

        // Load javascript variables (it will be load every time i add a control)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "dateValues" + _textBox.ClientID, javascriptVariables, true);

        // Load jQueryPlugin (it is loaded only once, and this is the problem)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(this.GetType(), "[[resourceName]]");
```

It works fine. **The problem is when i add this control to a page more than once**.

And it is because the script variables are loaded fine, but the RegisterClientScriptResource doesn't load the jQuery Plugin again! And i don't know how i can force the load! Because i can't set the resource key to the *RegisterClientScriptResource*

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want the jQuery Plugin to load multiple times?  It would seem to me that you'd want to load it once so that you can call the methods multiple times but not necessary have multiple copies of the methods there again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're taking the problem the right way.

- Using global variables (in js) especially when they're actually only used locally is a very **bad idea**. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice-javascript)
- Loading jQuery or a jQuery plugin more than once can also be a source of bugs. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731897/loading-jquery-twice-causes-an-error)

What i would do is to think of another way of passing variables to your javascript, something like data attributes.

You're probably having an html input generated with from server control, add data attributes for your dates :

```
<input type="text" ... data-mindate="01/01/2013" data-maxdate="12/31/2013" />
```

Next step is, instead of feeding the global variables to the datepicker function, use the data attributes :

```
$('#whatever').data('mindate');
```

or

```
$('#whatever').attr('data-mindate');
```

And a fast demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JjemN/