# Implementing fallback from Google AJAX Libraries API to local jQuery

Tags: jquery, cdn, google-ajax-api, fallback, google-ajax-libraries

After looking up the advantages and disadvantages of using Google's AJAX Libraries API instead of using jQuery locally, I saw that someone wrote in an answer (here on Stack Overflow, of course) that it's possible to get around the downtime that Google's API sometimes experiences by somehow **falling back to a local copy** of the library you use.

I want to use Google's AJAX Libraries API on my site, but I'm concerned about this possible downtime and I'm curious how such a fallback procedure can be implemented.

Has anybody ever tried doing this? Can you **point me towards some code** that accomplishes such a feat?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this answer

[Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo#answer-1014251)

Comment: Great, thanks! Looks like my question is a dupe...