# What's the best way to utilize jQuery-UI theme on CDN with local fallback?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, cdn

Is there anyway to load jQuery-UI theme from CDN, but with local fallback? Similar to the javascript fall-back outline here? [Google Hosted CDN with fall back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo)

Comment: We're all getting paranoid here, aren't we? ;)

Comment: lol Yi Jiang that's the same thing you said when I asked about the YUI cdn.

Comment: Well, allowing jquery-ui to fall-back is only half of the battle since the theme is also an integral part of the library.

Comment: I don't think this is paranoid - the googlecode cdn for jquery-ui css isn't serving the css for us right now, even though the jquery *is* being served.

Comment: Ugh, what's this then?
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Its not paranoid to want a fallback.  The fallback guarantees that dialogs and autocompletes still work, if the machine has trouble accessing other parts of the internet (or if your on a plane with no WiFi!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the resource loader [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/):

```
yepnope([{
  load: 'http:/­/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js',
  complete: function () {
    if ( !window.jQuery ) {
      yepnope('local/jquery.min.js');
    }
  }
}, {
  load: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js',
  complete: function () {
    if ( !window.jQuery.ui ) {
      yepnope('local/jquery-ui.min.js');
    }
  }
}]);
```

This will first try to load jQuery with local fallback, then load jQUery UI with local fallback.

Comment: Although the answer did not specified, yepnope also supports loading of CSS, not just js, which will allow loading the complete jQuery UI package (including the CSS) with fallback!

Comment: How exactly fallback CSS with yepnope?