# Benefits vs. Pitfalls of hosting jQuery locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cdn

We're currently pulling jQuery and jQueryUI (and jQueryUI CSS) libraries from the google CDN. I like this because I can call `google.load("jquery", "1");`
 and the latest jQuery 1.x.x will be used.

Now I am to pull the libraries locally because of security.

I'm happy to pull them locally but I'm wondering what are some of the other benefits and pitfalls to watch out for?

Comment: what security issues are we talking about?

Comment: I didn't ask. I'm guessing it's not so much Security but trying to control bandwidth by firewalling gmail etc.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The main benefit of having them on a CDN is that the files can be downloaded in parallel to files downloaded from your own website. This reduces latency on every page. So, the flip side of this is a pitfall of hosting locally - **increased latency**. The main reason for that is that browsers are limited in the number of connections that they can make at the same time to the same web domain. In IE6 this was defaulted to 2 concurrent connections to the same domain - *shared between all open windows of IE!!* In IE8+ it improved, defaulting to 6, which is inline with FF/Chrome, but still, if you have a lot of images and you are not using sprites, you will experience heavy latency.

Using a CDN, I would **always set the library version explicitly** rather than getting the latest one. This reduces the risk of new versions breaking your code. Not very likely with jQuery, but possible.

The other main benefit of using a CDN is **reduced traffic on your site**. If you pay per GB or you are on a virtual server with limited resources, you might find that overall site performance increases and hosting costs come down when you farm off some of your content to a public CDN.

Make sure you also read the other answer to this question by @Xaver. This is a very good trick

Comment: Another benefit of setting the library version explicitly is google gives it a longer cache time, For instance specifying 1.9.1 will give a longer cache lifetime than just requesting 1.9 (as a new jQuery 1.9 version might be released but 1.9.1 will always be the same).

Comment: uhhh - *revaxarts*?  I see no such answer, neither current nor deleted. What's the "very good trick"?

Answer (score 151):

I always use the CDN (Content Delivery Network) from Google. But just in case it's offline:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Grab Google CDN's jQuery and fallback to local if necessary

**Edit**:
If you don't need to support IE6 and your site has partial https usage you can remove the http as well:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Credit to the community: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go

Comment: XVIDEOS uses this solution now :P

Comment: I must be missing something here... Doesn't this approach assume that the CDN-loaded jQuery will load and be interpreted before the next line (`!window.jQuery...`) is interpreted? `<script>` tags are processed asynchronously, right?

Comment: `<script>` tags are processed synchronously! On the second line jQuery must be loaded already but just in case if not we inject some JS to load it locally. The `document.write` will never be executed if jQuery exists already.

Comment: Avoid document.write():
https://csswizardry.com/2023/01/why-not-document-write/

Answer (score 26):

Others have covered the benefits. Pitfalls:

- If you only include content from your own server, that's one server that needs to be running—and not blocked by firewalls etc—to make your site work. Pull script from a third party and now that's two servers that need to be running and unblocked to make your site work.
- Any site you pull `<script>` from can completely control the user's experience on your site. If Google were feeling evil they could put something in their copy of jQuery to log your keypresses, steal personal information from the page you're on to tie into their web tracking database, make you post “I love Google!” comments to every form, and so on.

Google probably aren't actually going to do that, but it's a factor that's out of your control, and certainly something to worry about with other script-hosting services. There have been incidents before where stats scripts have been compromised with malware loaders.

Before including any script from a third party—even on one single page of your site—you must 100% trust them with all user-accessible functionality visible on that hostname (including web-facing admin functions).

Comment: Google wouldn't do that...I LOVE GOOGLE...would they? :-p

Comment: Excellent points regarding security issues.

Comment: [Solution to point number 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)

Comment: Good points: never thought about how a remote CDN script could get hacked and then pulled down onto my site. Probably not common for major libraries like jQuery, jQueryUI, Boostrap, etc, but just like noted, smaller, less supported libraries could fall victim, especially if they're not kept up to date. Good points +1

Answer (score 16):

Google CDN:

- caching, good for performance, more users likely to have it already, and it downloads in parallel
- if ever, heaver forbid cdn goes down. you're screwed.
- if a new version breaks your existing plugins or site, you'll know about it possibly too late

Locally:

- development without being connected to the net is possible
- can still get some performance benefits by gzipping, in addition to minifying

Comment: however the jquery u load from google's cdn is minified.
Another plus to using a cdn is it is cleaner for your directory structure :)

Comment: `if a new version breaks your existing plugins or site, you'll know about it possibly too late` you can specify the version in the CDN link, to avoid that.

Answer (score 13):

I prefer to use my local version, because  I don't have control about what they will provide.
For example I don't want my users to get affected by google-analytics or anything similar, because this is a legal problem in my country.

Answer (score 9):

Benefits: (Specifically for Google's CDN)

1. Downloads in parallel with your files. Other answers address this further
2. Google's Servers are likely to be able to physically deliver the content faster
3. Common libraries and frameworks might already be on the user's machine, as the HTTP cache for a CDN is *universal* across all sites
4. Your bandwidth wouldn't have to go towards serving large library files

Answer (score 2):

Virtually every way you look at it, using Google's CDN is a good thing.

Performance will be improved (albeit fairly marginally, unless your site is really busy), and the amount of data your servers have to transmit will go down (although jQuery isn't exactly a massive thing to download), etc.

The only reason you wouldn't want to use it is if you don't trust Google. By using it, you are effectively giving Google an additional window of information into your site's traffic profile, including knowledge of URLs that you may otherwise not want to make public (eg secure areas of your site).

If you are paranoid about security then this may be enough to persuade you not to use them (after all, hosting it yourself isn't exactly going to slow your site down to a crawl), but in general most people would take the pragmatic view that Google knows enough about their site already that adding this won't make much difference.

Answer (score 2):

Probably I'm in minority nowadays, but I'd say that you don't want to use CDN unless you really need to. Key factors to start using it are:

- Cross geo users. If you host your website in the US but have visible amount of European users - CDN will improve the loading time.
- Big amount of users and\or big content, so one main server is not enough any more. One can think of any porn-video website (or Netflix, if you want). Video stream is a heavy load, with CDN would be much much less load on the main server.

But... the point is that these points are not really applicable to 90% of websites in the world. I bet you're not Facebook with millions of online users around the globe, you're not Pornhub with hundreds of GB transferred every second.

If your website is targeted to users in your city/country and capacity of one server is enough for amount of users you have - why would you ever want a CDN? It's quicker for your users in your city and simpler for you to fetch everything from your main server locally.

---

It was more about CDNs in general, now let me be closer to the actual question about jQuery or any other library.

If you want your website to stay accessible and working without maintenance for more than a year, let's say - put it locally. Libraries nowadays are being updated in a crazy tempo which you probably don't want to follow. And old versions are being deleted eventually. Moreover, the whole library can die (probably not applicable to jQuery though).

From my recent experience - I updated TinyMCE on the website I maintain from 3.x.x (dated 2012) to 5.x.x (dated Spring 2019). This website was working for 7(seven!) years without any maintenance in this part of the logic. There was no "minifying" concept back then and CDNs were not as common as now. But even if they would be common - you never know what will happen in 3-5-10 years from now. Usually you want your website to stay alive even without you maintaining it, don't you? However if you pull jQuery from CDN today, then this link may (and, probably, will) break in 5 years.

Solution with CDN AND fallback to local version as @Xaver suggested can be a good compromise. But... maybe just get rid of CDN link? ;)

Answer (score 0):

To me it really depends on how much control you desire to have.  If you are like me and need to develop on local host when working and traveling.   Having the jquery files local is better than having it hosted on google or else where.