# Is jquery UI is getting loaded when sourcing fro Google Ajax cdn?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

As has been discussed at breadth in many a forum, it is recommended to use Google's CDN for loading common js libraries. I am doing the same in my app and am loading jquery and jquery-ui from the Google cdn.

Now there have been quite a few instances where users have reported broken UI and that is a result of jquery ui not firing. e.g. jquery UI tabs/progress bars not working. Now I am wondering why this is happening and most probable reason seems to be jqueryui not getting downloaded properly from Google CDN.

Has anyone faced similar issues before? How to ensure that juqeryui is initialized/ready for each user?

Comment: My client switched to local versions of the jQueryUI and stylesheets because of occasional anomalies where the files wouldn't load for their clients. I have yet to reproduce this after months of hitting the pages for development; "hit refresh" was my expert opinion but that wasn't good enough.

Comment: yeah.. hit refresh does work, but many users are not returning to the app and I am wondering if they are facing any similar issues. hit refresh is definitely not a resolution. am thinking of switching to local versions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some fallback solutions (for jQuery proper) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832446/benefits-vs-pitfalls-of-hosting-jquery-locally) that may be helpful.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832446/benefits-vs-pitfalls-of-hosting-jquery-locally/3832530#3832530) in particular.