# Better way to import JavaScript and CSS files using CDN or from Local machine

Tags: javascript, css, import

In our project we imported javascript files in two types.

1) Imported from local machine

EXAMPLE:      `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

2) Imported from  CDN

EXAMPLE:    `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Which is the best options to import `java script` files or `css` files.When i use from `CDN` how to manage when the internet is not available

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is completely your wish. I think there is no better or worst way. If you have internet use cdn/local or if you are working offline use local.

Comment: Duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139372/referencing-external-javascript-vs-hosting-my-own-copy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Benefits vs. Pitfalls of hosting jQuery locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832446/benefits-vs-pitfalls-of-hosting-jquery-locally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this

for jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  if(typeof window.jQuery === 'undefined') {
    document.write(
      unescape("%3Cscript src='js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")
    );
  }
</script>
```

or this works

```
<script>
   !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

What this does is checks if jQuery exists if not it loads a local javascript file

just change to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

When you use from `CDN` if you want to make your page available even when its offline declare a manifest file so that browser caches your file.

```
<html manifest="path/filename.manifest">
```

Put above attribute to your `<html>`
Your manifest file looks something like this.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#one-line-comment
CACHE:
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js
#files that are to be loaded from cache.
NETWORK:
*
#files to be loaded online.
# * means all.
```