# About Google Hosted Libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, shared-libraries

I have a question about google hosted libraries.

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Does my web application really run faster if i use there libraries like `jquery` and `jquery ui` instead of the one that I saved in the libraries in my ftp root folder in my web host?

I'm questioning these because I'm running my web application in localhost but I'm planning to rent a webhost to make it online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Benefits vs. Pitfalls of hosting jQuery locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832446/benefits-vs-pitfalls-of-hosting-jquery-locally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google hosted libraries are basically a content delivery network (CDN). You can read up more about CDNs here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Content hosted on CDNs is replicated across data-centers around the world so that it can be accessed quickly wherever your end-user is located.

The content located on your web-domain might be accessible to you or a specific sub-set of your end-users fairly quickly but as the geographic distance between your webhost and the end-user grows, the page load times might become more noticeable.

CDNs also provide some additional benefits like: preventing DDOS attacks, isolating your host from security holes found in third-party libraries which otherwise may have rendered your host vulnerable if not patched in time, etc.