# what makes my website so slow?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have uploaded a website online http://www.perfectionpoolsabq.com/ but i wonder why it takes so long to load, i checked on the network and it doesnt really get stuck but it download image by image slowly, images arent big, none exceed 1 mb im running bootstrap and jquery and one simple image slider which seems to load before the images, is there any caching tips im forgetting??

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo URL; ?>js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you sure you're not using a 28.8k modem, or 2400 baud? loaded fine for me.

Comment: Here, run a speed test on your connection http://www.speedtest.net/ or use a benchmark since you did tag as PHP.

Comment: Er, it looks to me like most of the delay might be related to facebook and google crap ...

Comment: Use all js and css files as minified and compress yur images. Avoid unnessory php functions and loops.. use sprite image for static images.. use cache query for static queries.

Answer (score 1):

You have a total of 74 server calls, downloading a lot of images, scripts and so on. You shouldn't split up images and send them separately.

There is a plugin for Google Chrome (Dev Tools) which shows you what you could improve on your page. You can also access tool online, where you can also directly download optimized resources of your page: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.perfectionpoolsabq.com%2F

Answer (score -1):

It's working fine.

One thing you can do is download the jquery.min.js and call it locally.

Comment: and, what about for when they go "online"? not my dv here. But you may get more.

Comment: I am saying to download and call jquery.min.js from js folder like you are doing for bootstrap

Comment: what difference would the minified version do? we're talking what, a difference of how many kb's, 200?

Comment: @fred-ii : I think he is giving a valid suggestion. Make a copy of jquery in project instead of direct calling like ajax.google...... etc... if he explain in simple words than it would be useful

Comment: Using the Google CDN is pretty interesting because other website use it too. The chances are great that this script is in the cache of your browser, and won't be loaded again.

Comment: @AdrianTombu using a CDN has also a lot of downfalls: you are relying on a different server (uptime) and much worse: you rely completely on the goodwill of the CDN provider not to harm your page. The provider of a CDN can do whatever he wants with your page (even a CSS CDN has some security issues..)

Comment: Heres a related topic..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832446/benefits-vs-pitfalls-of-hosting-jquery-locally