# How do I install masonry or other javascript in rails? (not using gems)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cdn, masonry

I wanted [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/#install) for my Rails 4.2 project and initially installed it via the [masonry-rails gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/masonry-rails) and then wasted an evening until I realized that the gem was using an outdated version of Masonry. This will be my first attempt to add javascript to my Rails app without a gem. From the [installation docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/#install) the options are:  **Download**, **CDN**, **Package managers (bower/npm)**

I used **CDN** by simply adding

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

to the top of my index.html.erb view file that will use the script. Is this correct?

What is the advantage/disadvantage of using **CDN** instead of **Download** or **Package managers** and if I want to add `masonry.pkgd.min.js` manually to my project how would i do so?

[This has some good related info](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the advantage/disadvantage of using CDN instead of Download

To know the pros and cons of CDN vs Local script, see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3832502/1715409)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3832498/1715409)

> How to manually add them in project

There are 2 ways

1. Either put them(e.g. masonry.pkgd.min.js) under  `app/assets/javascripts` and require them in application.js as  `//= require masonry.pkgd.min.js` but only if you do not have this line `//= require_tree .` Because require_tree will load all js files under app/assets/javascripts folder
2. Or put them in `vendor/assets/javascripts`. But in this case you must require it in application.js file

> added masonry script to the top of index.html.erb view file that will use the script. Is
>   this correct?

It is correct in the sense that it will load only to that particular view. Now if you put the same in `application.html.erb` or loaded it via assets then the same js script will load on every views.

Comment: he also asked whether his use of CDN in index.html.erb by calling `<script src="..."></script>` is correct or not. I'm interested in this point, can you pls add info to your answer?

Comment: @davideghz I added my opinion whether adding embedded js is good or bad. It may be different for different persons.