# jquery-tools fallback if CDN fails

Tags: jquery-tools, fallback

I'm using the for falling back and serving jquery locally if Googles CDN fails, following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo#answer-1014251).

Does anyone have advice for how to fall back on local jquerytools if the CDN version fails? There's a similar [technique for Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/forum/7/14272#) discussed in Flowplayer forum, but I haven't figured out how to do it for jquerytools.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flashembed object from jQuery Tools, like this:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.flashembed || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```