# Google CDN for jquery or prototypejs or any other if not loaded

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, google-cdn

I am using google CDN for jQuery and prototypeJS library in my pages. For any reason, if those library are not loaded what measure can I take so that my pages function properly.

### EDIT

I have found this link in SO

[Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo)

which is very similar to my question.

Sorry to ask the same thing which has been asked already.

Comment: Do you want to check in javascript code if jQuery has been loaded? Please, clarify your question.

Comment: @Pavel, I want to check whether my library file has been loaded or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo)

Comment: @alex, I have said it in my EDIT part.

Comment: That comment is auto generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')) {
  // Insert your local copy

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'to/local/copy/jquery.js';

  var scriptHook = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  scriptHook.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scriptHook);

}
```

Comment: should I place this code just after the script tag for google cdn?

Answer (score 2):

[have a look at this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/01/21/using-cdn-hosted-jquery-with-a-local-fall-back-copy.aspx)

Comment: is document.write a good approach for including script tag to dom?