# jquery ui - how to use google CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cdn, google-cdn

I want to use Google CDN for jQuery and jQuery UI..

I'm using the answer from here for jQuery.
[Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo)

but i don't understand this bit:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
```

so how can i do it for jQuery UI?
also, will this work with custom jQuery UI theme as this produces a custom js file too?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can make the call using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also link to other Ui themes by changes the name of the theme. In This case change the name base to any other theme name `/base/jquery-ui.css` to any other theme.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Check out the jQuery UI Blog for a link of all CDN links http://blog.jqueryui.com/

If you're concerned that the Google CDN ever fails or goes down, you can fall back to a local copy when the CDN is offline (this example is baked into templates like HTML5 Boilerplate):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>')
</script>
```

Comment: You can also get your jQuery from Microsofts CDN. See the jQuery blog link above to access the links. Also Read 3 reason why you should get your jQuery from Google and not local host  http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Answer (score 10):

If you are having a custom jQuery UI theme, you have to host that on your own server. Google only hosts the [main jQuery UI themes](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/05/latest-jquery-and-jquery-ui-theme-links.html).

If you want to check whether or not the jQuery UI library has loaded, you can do this:

```
if (jQuery.ui) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list, just change to the version you need.

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui