# jquery from cdn

Tags: jquery, cdn

How do i load the following in cdn and if they fail i would wnat my local file to load if this fails

1. **Google's CDN** :   jquery.min.js  and   jquery-ui.min.js.
2. **Microsoft's CDN :** jQuery.Validate.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fOR jQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); //local
}
</script>
```

For Jquery Ui

```
if (jQuery.ui) {
     document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/scripts/jqueryui-1.8.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); //local
}
```

For Jquery validate

```
if(!jQuery().validate) {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); //local
}
```

Links 
MS validate.js - http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.min.js

Google jquery.min.js - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js

Google jquery.ui.js - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Google JqueryUi theme- (change base to one of the core theme name) http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 15):

this is how guys from [html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/) do this

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the jquery object exists after including the file so you have a failsafe (very rare)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); //local
}
</script>
```

So, for the links you asked for

MS validate.js - http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.min.js

Google jquery.min.js - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js

Google jquery.ui.js - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Have a look at this question : [Microsoft CDN for jQuery or Google CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447184/) They talk about your problem as well

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

jQueryUI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js

for more info. http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

for fallback something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/path/to/your/jquery' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
if (typeof jQuery.ui == 'undefined') 
{
    // UI Not loaded
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/jquery.ui.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: how do i check if jquery ui is loaded and validate is loaded

Comment: using jQuery.ui have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html) to check if jquery has loaded or not.

For loading jQuery [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) will certainly help you.

Also you can check if validate plugin is loaded or not on [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jquery-plugin-is-loaded.html).

Comment: that's for the most validate.js what about jquery ui

Comment: @WebDeveloper well jquery ui is also a plugin after all, so checking any method i.e. any method of jquery ui will do that like validate

Answer (score 1):

Already answered a similar questions at [jquery ui - how to use google CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206666/jquery-ui-how-to-use-google-cdn/5206671#5206671)

You can make the call using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also load jQuery from Microsoft CDN at

```
<script src=" http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also link to other Ui themes by changes the name of the theme. In This case change the name base to any other theme name `/base/jquery-ui.css` to any other theme.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Check out the jQuery UI Blog for a link of all CDN links http://blog.jqueryui.com/

If you want to revert back to your host in case Google failed, you can do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: how do i check if jquery ui is loaded and validate is loaded

Comment: Check the last part of my answer and just replace the file name to reference jQuery ui.