# javascript - import jQuery as module

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox addon and need to import jQuery.
Tried `import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34340392/14846640) but didn't work and I should use like `import(browser.runtime.getURL('/js/jquery.js')).then(jq => {});`, but getting error jq is not a function on code `jq('#app')` also getting same problem for `$('#app')`.

Comment: Why dont you try use the cdn for `jquery` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415821/jquery-from-cdn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latest jQuery version on Google's CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608242/latest-jquery-version-on-googles-cdn)

Comment: because can't load modules from CDN in addons