# is it possible to detect what components are inside a jquery-ui.min.js file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, components

I need to get another version of jQuery UI, to replace the existing one (is pretty old and I have compatibility issues).

The problem is that I don't know all the components that are used at this time by that website and I would like to keep my jQuery UI file at its smallest size.

Any way to list all components contained inside ? Or, the only way is to study my site and find out what's being used there?

[jQuery download link with customizable components](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Comment: How many files does this website have? How many JS files? It could potentially be easier to look through the JS files and see what gets used.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many CDNs instead of hosting it yourself? [jquery ui - how to use google CDN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206666/jquery-ui-how-to-use-google-cdn)

Comment: At the top of the jquery-ui file is a comment which lists all the included components `* Includes: jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, ...`

Comment: mine doesnt't have that comment. I was hoping for a function or something that will list all components... but I think I will check by hand. I can't remote hosting because the site must be functional when cut off from web too. It's a website-like application, actually. Not a real website.