# How do I ensure my javascript only executes after all external <script src="..."> have loaded their contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Our website uses the Google API to execute google searches. The problem I am experiencing is that the following code fails...

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('search', '1');
</script>
```

It fails with the following error message:

> 'google' is undefined

My guess is that this is happening because the Google API has not loaded completely before the script executes.

Should I use JQuery's document.ready?  I read that this will start executing script when the DOM has finished loading. I assume this does not include loading external resources like scripts, stylesheets and images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specify `defer` or `async` attributes, `<script>`s always load and execute sequentially; the second script will only be executed after the first one has loaded and executed. (Note that this doesn’t necessarily mean you’ll already notice a difference at this point; for example, I could execute the script `window.onload = function() { alert(42); };` right now, but I will only see its result when the `onload` event fires.)

If you’re using this code:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load('search', '1');
</script>
```

And you get an error message saying `google` is undefined, it means the first script failed to load.

Comment: Very useful advice, thanks Mathias. So the code *should* work fine, but there was a problem loading the script. Interesting...

Comment: @willem Yes, but since Google’s servers almost never go down it’s likely there is/was a problem with your connection.

Answer (score 2):

No-repro

```
<script src="http://google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>google.load("jquery", "1");</script>
<script>alert($);</script>
```

It does work, there is no need for an API key.

Can you check the request it is making? (with Firebug or something) It might be a problem with your connection... [That is why there is a fallback for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014203/340760) you can implement. As for the loader you will have to check why the request is failing.