# Why use \x3C instead of < when generating HTML from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, escaping

I see the following HTML code used a lot to load jQuery from a content delivery network, but fall back to a local copy if the CDN is unavailable (e.g. in the [Modernizr docs](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#load)):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

My question is, why is the last `<` character in the `document.write()` statement replaced with the escape sequence `\x3C`? `<` is a safe character in JavaScript and is even used earlier in the same string, so why escape it there? Is it just to prevent bad browser implementations from thinking the `</script>` inside the string is the real script end tag? If so are there really any browsers out there that would fail on this?

As a follow-on question, I've also seen a variant using `unescape()` (as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014251/440921)) in the wild a couple of times too. Is there a reason why that version always seems to substitute *all* the `<` and `>` characters?

Comment: Would this be true from within a script file or eval'd block?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When the browser sees `</script>`, it considers this to be the end of the script block (since the HTML parser has no idea about JavaScript, it can't distinguish between something that just appears in a string, and something that's *actually meant* to end the script element). So `</script>` appearing literally in JavaScript that's inside an HTML page will (in the best case) cause errors, and (in the worst case) be a huge security hole.

That's why you somehow have to prevent this sequence of characters to appear. Other common workarounds for this issue are `"<"+"/script>"` and `"<\/script>"` (they all come down to the same thing).

While some consider this to be a "bug", it actually *has to* happen this way, since, as per the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html), the HTML part of the user agent is completely separate from the scripting engine. You can put all kinds of things into `<script>` tags, not just JavaScript. The W3C mentions VBScript and TCL as examples. Another example is the [jQuery template plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/), which uses those tags as well.

But even within JavaScript, where you could suggest that such content in strings could be recognized and thus not be treated as ending tags, the next ambiguity comes up when you consider comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript">foo(42); // call the function </script>
```

– what should the browser do in this case?

And finally, what about browsers that don't even know JavaScript? They would just ignore the part between `<script>` and `</script>`, but if you gave different semantics to the character sequence `</script>` based on *the browsers knowledge of JavaScript*, you'd suddenly have two different results in the *HTML parsing stage*.

Lastly, regarding your question about substituting *all* angle brackets: I'd say at least in 99% of the cases, that's for obfuscation, i.e. to hide (from anti-virus software, censoring proxies (like in your example (nested parens are awesome)), etc.) the fact that your JavaScript is doing some HTML-y stuff. I can't think of good technical reasons to hide anything but `</script>`, at least not for reasonably modern browsers (and by that, I mean pretty much anything newer than Mosaic).

Comment: I just amended the question to that effect, probably as you were typing your answer. Are there really any modern browsers that would fail on this?

Comment: Most, I think. I know for sure that Chrome interprets it as a closing tag. (Checked yesterday)

Comment: Would this happen with a CDATA section wrapping the script?

Comment: @Mark — All browsers would "fail" on that, because `</script>` is *supposed* to be treated as an end tag.

Comment: @Marcin — Not if the document was served as `application/xhtml+xml` and parsed as XML, and not if the document was parsed using a real SGML parser … but it would with a tag soup or HTML 5 parser.

Comment: @Quentin, awesome, thanks for clarifying. What's up with HTML5 changing the behaviour?

Comment: @Mark: Expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: Sorry, can't help myself from adding a thank-you comment: Big Thanks for the clarity of the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Some parsers handle the `<` version as the closing tag and interpret the code as

```
<script>
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js">
</script>
```

`\x3C` is hexadecimal for `<`. Those are interchangable within the script.