# Trouble inserting JavaScript var (containing stmt that contains markup) into <script>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a script dynamically (which is why it ends up in a var) but I've simplified this example. The problem I'm having is that the browser interprets the span tags inside the script as actual spans, rather than as part of the script. I've looked at all kinds of resources on escaping characters and html encoding/decoding, but either those aren't relevant issues or I'm just not getting it.

How can I write the span inside the dynamically-generated script so that the browser interprets it as part of the script and not as a span tag that it should render?

### page.html file

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var formScript = '    $(document).on("ready", function () {';
        formScript += $().BuildScript();
        $("script#dynamic-script").append(formScript + '});');
    });
</script>

<script id="dynamic-script"></script>
```

### functions.js file

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.BuildScript = function () {

        var stmtsToAdd = '';

        stmtsToAdd += '$("#X").on("change", function () {' +
            '   if ($(this).val() == "1" && !$("#label-and-control_Y").is(":visible")) {' +
            '       $("#label-and-control_Y").show("fast");' +
            '       $("#control_Y").addClass("required");' +
            '       $("#control_Y").closest("div.control").prev().empty.append("<span class=&quot;required-field-indicator&quot;>");' +
            '   }' +
            '});';

        return stmtsToAdd;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

### variations

I have also tried using a variety of special characters, both with and without escaping backslashes (just in case I was misunderstanding something), with always the same result

```
"\u003cspan class=\\u0022required-field-indicator\\u0022\u003eRequired\u003c\/span\u003e"

"\x3cspan class=\x22required-field-indicator\x22\x3eRequired\x3c/span\x3e"
```

I also read that jQuery's html() was decoding, which is why I've tried append(), text(), and appendChild().

### result

[image: resulting broken script]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8231048/218196 and any of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+escape+html+%3Cscript%3E

Comment: Thanks, Felix, but I didn't see (or understand) anything in your suggestions that differs from what I've added to the **variations** section of the post, which I'd already tried but tried again.

Comment: So, did you actually try `"\\x3cspan class=\x22required-field-indicator\x22\\x3eRequired\\x3c/span\\x3e"`?

Comment: No, and that worked! Can you tell me why I would need to encode AND backslash escape the angle brackets? (Actually, I escaped the double quotes, as they were inside double quotes: `"\\x3cspan class=\\x22required-field-indicator\\x22\\x3eRequired\\x3c/span\\x3e"`.)

Comment: Because you are creating JavaScript source code via JavaScript. You literally want to create the character sequence `\x3c`. However, if you simply put that in a string literal, it will convert to `<` (just type `"\x3c"` in the console). Hence you have to escape the \. `'"\x3cspan"'` results in `"<span"` and  `'"\\x3cspan"'` results in `"\x3cspan"`.

Comment: Correcting myself, on second thought - Even though I admit that I'm not sure why I would need to both encode and backslash escape the angle brackets, I really could swear I've tried that character combo before - like two days ago when I first started banging my head against the wall.

Comment: I realize that this might be a duplicate, but if you'd like to post an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted. Thank you very much for your assistance!