# Javascript - Header font size change using for loop

Tags: javascript, css

I would like some help with the following code.

What it's supposed to do is to create a button on a site that when pressed displays the same message, each time using one of the headers h6 to h1.

Here's the code.

```
<p>
<button type="button" onClick="headers()"> Show Headers</button>
<script> function headers() {
for(num = 6; num > 0 ; num--) {
  num.toString();
  document.write("<p>" + "<h(num)>" + "Message") <!-- That is the part that I cannot make to work. I wanted the num in the <hnum> to change as the for loop progresses so I can have h6 h5 h4...etc, dunno if it's possible to do it that way though :/  -->
  }
}
</script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close! see this: https://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/

```
for(num = 6; num > 0 ; num--) {
  document.write("<p>" + "<h"+num+">" + "Message");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another EDIT: Actually you also need the end tag, and you won't need the `<p>` :

```
document.write("<h" + num + ">" + "Message" + "</h" + num + ">");
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop you're trying to write should look like this:

```
for(var num = 6; num > 0; num--) {
  document.write("<h"+num+">" + "Message" + "</h"+num+">");
}
```

Also, there's no need for the heading element to be nested inside the `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

To understand Why I wrote \x3Cp instead of "<"
read this:
[Why use \x3C instead of < when generating HTML from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231048/why-use-x3c-instead-of-when-generating-html-from-javascript)

```
for(num = 6; num > 0 ; num--) {
  num.toString();

  document.write("\x3Cp>" + "\x3Ch(num)>" + "Message")
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Ok i will try next time , Thanks For Your advice