# Client side template engine with XML support

Tags: xml, xpath, handlebars.js, template-engine, client-side-templating

Is there any client side template engine with XML/ XPath support? I looked into handlebars, mustache, underscore etc. but looks like they only can accept a JSON object as it's context.

What I'm really looking for is to have xpath in expressions:

```
<div>
   <h1>{{/person/address/street}} </h1>
</div>
```

Data:

```
<person>
    <name>Some name</name>
    <address>
        <street>5th Lane</street>
    <address>
</person>
```

And the JS code like:

```
Template.render('template.html', data.xml);
```

I understand it's possible to transform XML to JSON either at client-side or server-side and use handlebars. But I just wanted to avoid this transformation in order to reduce processing time.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate templating engine that supports XML and XPath is, of course, [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), which can be [run on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942399/290085).

Also, Saxonica has a library, [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml), that'll allow XSLT 2.0 to run on web browsers.

Comment: XSLT is not a choice for me as the style-sheet sooner becomes not maintainable and no support for mobile browsers. However why do we need Saxon-CE to run XSTL on web browsers? XSTL is supported by major web browsers and does not require any libraries.

Comment: *Sooner becomes not maintainable*:  Not true, but would not encourage its use on browsers over server-side, so do agree with you in that regard.  To answer your other question: XSLT 1.0 is supported natively to varying degrees by the major web browsers.   XSLT 2.0 is not, but is by Saxon-CE.