# XPath query not working in browser XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a simple XML file: customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="web.xsl"?>
<purple> 
    <customer cid="1">
        <fname>John</fname> 
        <lname>Klingard</lname> 
        <apt>27</apt> 
        <street>30th Winstonhut St.</street> 
        <pobox>199183</pobox> 
    </customer>
</purple>
```

This is my XSL file: web.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html> 
        <head> 
            <title>Customer</title> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
            <xsl:for-each select="//customer[@cid='1']">
            <xsl:value-of select="fname"/> <br/>
            <xsl:value-of select="lname"/> <br/>    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that there is no output on the browser from the query. I am using Google Chrome. 
I suspect that there might be something wrong with the XPath query itself.
But, am I missing anything else?

Comment: Do a search for XSLT + Chrome.

Comment: @har07 It doesn't work on IE either!

Comment: I tried your samples at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016032701.xml with the stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016032701.xsl and it works fine with Firefox, IE, Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Please state what output you are expecting  I tried it with Firefox 44 and got "John\nKlingard\n"  so I believe that it works for me.  I also tried Chrome 49 but got a blank page.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks but what surprises me is that it works online but when I download it and run the local files, it gives me a blank page.

Comment: @ssimm Yes, that's exactly what I'm expecting as output! Also, thanks.. I tried it with Firefox and it works! I'm switching to Firefox to continue with the work.

Comment: @michael.hor257k tried to direct you to the answer 6 hours ago.  Did you read his suggested references?  Chrome won't run local XSLT due to security concerns.  See details in the links contained in the duplicate notice.

Comment: @kjhughes Yes, I did read it. It was suggested that I run Chrome from cmd using the --allow-file-access-from-files flag. I attempted this yet it never worked.

Comment: You've drawn the wrong conclusion.  [**To run XSLT in the browser**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29942399/290085),  ***load from a server*** [**instead of from local files**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33801287/290085).

Comment: @kjhughes Oh I understand now! Thank you so much.. I ran it on an Apache server and it works!