# XSLT failing to display transformed XML in web browser

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I've been having problems getting my XSLT file to get its XSLT functions to display, and after a bit of trial and error/debugging with Blueprint, it appears my problem has to do with my namespacing and (possibly) my XSD file. I've spent an hour with my professor trying to find the bug/problem, but to no avail.

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="movies.xsl"?>

<movieRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://www.example.com/comicbooks/movies/ns"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/comicbooks/movies/ns movies.xsd">    

    <movie>

        <movieTitle>Captain America: Civil War</movieTitle>
        <genre>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</genre>
        <rating>8.13</rating>
        <length>147 min</length>
        <releaseDate>May 6th, 2016</releaseDate>

     </movie>

</movieRoot>
```

**XSD File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.example.com/comicbooks/movies/ns"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/comicbooks/movies/ns">

    <xs:element name="movieRoot">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="movie" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="movieTitle" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="genre" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="rating" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="length" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="releaseDate" type="xs:string" />
                       </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**XSLT File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="movies.css" />
        </head>

        <body>

            <h1><xsl:value-of select= "movieRoot/movie/releaseDate" /></h1>

        </body>
        </html>


     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your XSLT isn't taking into account the default namespace of your XML.**

1. Declare a namespace prefix on your `xsl:stylesheet` element:

   ```
   xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com/comicbooks/movies/ns"
   ```
2. And change your `xsl:value-of` to use the newly defined namespace
   prefix:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select= "ns:movieRoot/ns:movie/ns:releaseDate" />
   ```

Then your XML will be rendered via your XSLT to show the date as an `h1`.

**Notes**:

- An XSD doesn't come into play for displaying HTML transformed from XML.
- Chrome will not load locally originating XSLT due to security concerns.
  Firefox will.
- See also [XSLT not working in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29941662/290085)

Comment: Yes! That did the trick, thank you very much.