# XSLT: Trouble concatenating words with an attribute

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am having trouble with pulling the YEAR attribute from my xml file and concatenating it with characters.

I am trying to get the xml to look like this:

```
<h1>CIA World 2008 Factbook - Countries</h1>
```

"2008" is apart of the YEAR attribute.
Here is a piece of the xml document that I am using:

```
<WFB YEAR="2008">
```

WFB is the root element in the document.

So far I have this..

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="element[@YEAR]">
     <element>
      <h1><xsl:value-of select=
       "concat(CIA World ', @YEAR, ' Factbook - Countries)"/></h1>
     </element>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I feel like I am over complicating it, though...

Comment: `@WFB` is not a attribute

Comment: Thanks, bhantol. I edited my original post.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - esp. WRT the input.

Comment: Why do you expect `match="element[@YEAR]"` to match `<WFB YEAR="2008">`? Use `match="*[@YEAR]"` to match any element with a `YEAR` attribute or `match="/*[@YEAR]"` to match the root element with that attribute or obviously `match="WBF[@YEAR]"` to match on the element name you have shown.

Answer (score 3):

Given the following input:

**XML**

```
<WFB YEAR="2008"/>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/WFB">
    <html>
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('CIA World ', @YEAR, ' Factbook - Countries')"/>
        </h1>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<html>
   <h1>CIA World 2008 Factbook - Countries</h1>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael.hor257k! I just tried out your example code, but for some reason when I transform my XML, my html file shows up empty. Any advice?

Comment: This code will generate the shown HTML given the shown XML.  If you're having trouble with it, you'll have to do a much better job of **relaying exactly how you're running the code**.  If you're trying to run XSLT in the browser, see [**XSLT not working in web browser**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941662/xslt-not-working-in-web-browser).