# xml not formatted when in a different path of xsl file

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt

I am trying to open an  xml file with firefox. This file contains the line

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/home/myname/myfolder/Template.xsl'?>
```

and Template.xsl is a file in the same folder of the xml file. 
In this way I can correctly display the xml but I need to move it in a different folder.
The problem is that if I move the xml into a different folder and try to open it, it doesn't seem to read the xsl file anymore (except if the new folder is one of: /home, /home/myname/ or /home/myname/myfolder).
I can't understand this behaviour, because in the href option I am writing the absolut path of the xsl file. Is there any way to visualize the xml if I move it in different path from the xsl file?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the console of Firefox for error messages, it will probably tell you that the access was denied.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the security measures of FireFox (and even more Chrome) will prevent opening a local file from anywhere but the current directory (of the XML file).

So - if using the XML+XSLT combination for creating your website - keep your XML and your XSLT always in the same directory.

---

**Update:**

- **Chrome:** See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3839054/1305969) which states that Chrome "has addressed in a controversial way [...] blocking XML files from accessing local XSLT files [**even**] in the same directory[...]"
- **FireFox:** The [general rules concerning the XML+XSLT situation do apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942399/1305969). (Also have a look a the (absolute/relative) filenames in the question of this answer.)

In general, the [following comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70088#c22) seems to describe the current state concerning Chrome very well:

> XML has different security properties than CSS or JavaScript.  In the web security model, CSS and JavaScript are publicly executable, but XML is private.  For example, you can run a JavaScript library from another web site, but you can't read their XML.  Unfortunately, XSLT has a security flaw where applying an XSLT to your document allows you to read the contents of the XML that makes up the XSLT.  That means a malicious document can apply an XSLT (e.g., an file saved by your word processor to your local file system) and steal information from it.
>
> Given his situation, we're faced with a trade-off.  We can allow local XSLT, which is a feature that some fraction of the audience will enjoy, but doing so opens a security hole.  In this case, we've weighed the alternatives and decided that the security of the many out weighs supporting this feature for the few.

So, *FireFox* is better than *Chrome* - but both suck in that regard.

Comment: Thanks... So you are telling me that there is no solution to my problem... Unfortunately I can't keep xml and xsl files in the same directory. My xmls are generated by a C++ script and I need to organize them in folders with the daily date

Comment: @fool: I extended my answer. You can try relative path's to solve your problem, but I cannot give you any guarantee that this would work.