# Trying to style HTML color attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

Any one Comfortable with XML and XSLT here:
In my XMLl I am trying to color two different "p" tags with different attributes using XSLT below:

```xsl
<xsl:template match="p">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl: when test="p/@color='red'"><span style="color:#00ff00"><xsl:value-of select="p"/></span></xsl:when>
  <xsl: when test="p/@color='green'"> <span style="color:#ff0000"> <xsl:value-of select="p"/></span></xsl:when>
  <xsl: otherwise><xsl:value-of select="p"/></xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

XML looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
<p color="red">Last paragraph incorrect</p>
<p>A Second paragraph</p>
<p color="green">The First paragraph</p>
<p color="green">Anthony Gonsalwes</p>
</body>
<body>
<l color="green"> kumarswamy</l>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The closing `</span>` elements are missing in your XSL stylesheet.

Comment: love you @HeikoTheißen, i was not able to see this small thing for last 2-3 hrs , thanks

Comment: @HeikoTheißen , so i am trying to add an xslt file inside XML but while rendering on browser it does not render anything at all, any ideas on that

Comment: Please update your question with a description of this follow-up problem. I don't understand it.

Comment: The `color` attribute has been obsolete for so long I couldn't even remember ever using it.

Comment: Re XSLT in browsers, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29941662/3016153

Comment: <xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl: when test="p/@color='red'">
    <span style="color:#00ff00">
     <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
    </span>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl: when test="p/@color='green'">
    <span style="color:#ff0000">
     <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
    </span>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl: otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

if i am taking this xslt just to color p with red arrtibute as red, green with 'green' and otherwise, It is not giving me anything , can you spot any errors here @HeikoTheißen

Comment: @Rob if you can Please give inputs for the above coloring doubt as well

Comment: Please don't write code in comments, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template matches `p`. This establishes the context for the relative paths you use inside the template. It means that your condition:

```
<xsl:when test="p/@color='red'">
```

will be true only if the current `p` has a child `p` element with a `color` attribute with value of 'red'. This is of course not true for any `p` element in your XML. You should be testing instead:

```
<xsl:when test="@color='red'">
```

and instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="p"/>
```

you need:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Comment: You also show spaces in `xsl: when`. That's a syntax error.