# Can't display XML in browser after adding XSLT stylesheet?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Issue Description:
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to display an XML file with associated XSLT styling in a web browser (specifically Microsoft Edge). The XML file contains bibliographic data and references an XSLT stylesheet for rendering. However, when I try to open the XML file in the browser, nothing is displayed. Instead, I'm seeing an error message related to "Cross-Origin Request" and "Same Origin Policy."
Error Message:
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/TPXML/biblio1.xsl. Reason: CORS request does not use HTTP."

biblio.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE BIBLIO SYSTEM "./biblio0.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./biblio1.xsl"?>
<BIBLIO>
    <ETUDIANT code="E1" nom="Missaoui" prenom="Mostapha" age="20">
        <LIVRE id="L1" titre="Java" dateEmprunt="2022-11-11" rendu="NON"/>
        <LIVRE id="L2" titre="XML" dateEmprunt="2022-12-11" rendu="OUI"/>
    </ETUDIANT>
    <ETUDIANT code="E2" nom="Missaoui" prenom="Abderrahman" age="20">
        <LIVRE id="L1" titre="Java" dateEmprunt="2022-01-11" rendu="NON"/>
    </ETUDIANT>
</BIBLIO>
```

biblio0.dtd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT BIBLIO (ETUDIANT+) >
<!ELEMENT ETUDIANT (LIVRE+) >
<!ELEMENT LIVRE EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST ETUDIANT 
             code NMTOKEN #REQUIRED 
             nom CDATA #REQUIRED 
             prenom CDATA #REQUIRED 
             age NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST LIVRE 
             id NMTOKEN #REQUIRED 
             titre CDATA #REQUIRED 
             dateEmprunt CDATA #REQUIRED  
             rendu (OUI|NON) "NON" >
```

biblio1.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Biblio</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h3>Liste des etudiats</h3>
                <xsl:for-each select="/BIBLIO/ETUDIANT">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Code : <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></li>
                        <li>Code : <xsl:value-of select="@nom"/></li>
                        <li>Code : <xsl:value-of select="@age"/></li>
                    </ul>
                    <table border="1" width="75%">
                        <tr><!--ligne-->
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Titre</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Rendu</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="LIVRE">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@titre"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@dateEmprunt"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@rendu"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Steps Taken:

I've corrected errors in the XSLT file to ensure proper syntax and attribute access.
I've ensured that all files (biblio.xml, biblio0.dtd, biblio1.xsl) are located in the same directory.
I've checked file permissions to ensure they are accessible to the browser.
I've attempted to open the XML file in Microsoft Edge and other browsers, but the issue persists.
Expected Outcome:
I expect the XML file to be rendered as an HTML document according to the transformation rules specified in the XSLT stylesheet when opened in a web browser.

Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking guidance on resolving the "Cross-Origin Request" issue and enabling the display of the XML data with proper styling using XSLT in a web browser. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Load over HTTP(S), not from the file system. These days it is kind of your only option and it is easy to run a local web server e.g. as a Python module or a Node.js module for a local directory on your file system.

Comment: **Low-level tips:** See answers at [duplicate q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29941662/290085).  **High-level tip**: Browser-native XSLT should be considered dead tech at this point.  If you have an application that requires XSLT to be run in the browser, use Saxon-JS.  Otherwise, everything from learning to production deployment of XSLT should be done outside of the browser.