# Is it safe to reference google's JQuery library?

Tags: jquery

I have included a reference to [Google's JQuery library](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js) in my markup:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is it safe to do this? How do I know Google won't change the address, or remove it altogether? I really can't afford to have my app break without warning.

What do other people do?

Comment: If google did change or remove it half the internet would break.

Comment: Aren't they likely to get rid of the old version 1.4.2 at some stage in the future? I want to put it in my code and forget about it, not keep updating it.

Comment: At some stage, but i'd expect maybe 20 years?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have the best of both worlds. Use theirs for fast, possibly pre-cached, delivery and in case their server goes down (more likely than them moving it) fallback to your own:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/path/to/your/jquery' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Taken from: [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo#answer-1014251)

Comment: Really good way to do it, probably the best. However, that said, I don't plan on changing my code because I just can't imagine Google's CDN going down xP

Comment: That's exactly what Paul Irish's HTML5 Boilerplate does. Also handy if, say, you're going to be working on something on your laptop while on a plane without internet access or somesuch (which happened to me a couple of weeks ago).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's completely safe.  It's also hosted on Google's CDN making it load faster, in most cases, than loading from your own server.

Comment: Not to mention a lot of people probably have google CDN resources cached, making it possibly even faster.

Comment: What about countries where Google domain name is blocked?

Comment: @Urbycoz: that's what the fallback in Mauvis Ledford's answer is for, providing a local copy of jQuery just in case the CDN version is unavailable for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, it is what you *should do*!

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Answer (score 0):

Google offers it for free. Google's servers are fast and above all **you save your bandwidth**.

Answer (score -1):

It is 100% safe to use Google's hosted jQuery file. In fact, it is actually faster because browsers can download multiple files at once from different servers. Also, if the user has visited a website that uses Google's jQuery before, the script will already be in the cache, causing the page to load faster.

Ad@m