# Reference jquery from aspx webpage in CRM 2011

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, html, webresource

I've created a web resource with the jquery script, this is the url:

"http://dynamics:port/somelib/WebResources/new_orgName/scripts/jquery1.7.2.min"

I've created a new aspx web page and put it in the navbar in 'account' form.

I've added to the 'account' form properties the jquery script, but when the aspx webpage loads, it doesnt recognizes the "$" symbol of jquery.

How do I reference the jquery from the webpage? Do I still need specifically reference the jquery file from the webpage?

Comment: add this in your page top `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` further if you have any conflict also look into `.noConflict` API.

Comment: But then I'll use the online jquery and the web resource that I've added is useless. What if I want to work with my script offline?

Comment: lol `:)` your source is `http://`vnot sure how will you access offline `:)` **but** anyhoo try this: change the src `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://dynamics:port/somelib/WebResources/new_orgName/scripts/jquery1.7.2.min'>` **or** set the web config flie correctly and use absolute or relative path accordingly. hope it helps

Comment: good point :) hh..I ment that wether I should add jquery as a web resource or its better practice just to use the online version and only add web resources of scripts that I have written?

Comment: It depends Greg, `:)` < according to your need / purpose > use it either way ; **or** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382639/is-it-safe-to-reference-googles-jquery-library **and**  http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/ might help &&and** lemme know if this answers your Question I will set this as answer.

Comment: Okies Greg I will set this as Answer in that case bruv `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our conversation above:

Add this in your page top or master page.

**Scripts**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>‌

​<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

further if you have any conflict also look into .noConflict API.

< according to your need / purpose > use it either way ; or [Is it safe to reference google's JQuery library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382639/is-it-safe-to-reference-googles-jquery-librar) Might help to make decision.

Rest this will help the cause.