# How JS file can be download programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

most of the time we include script tag in html head tag. like

```
 <Head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I want that I don't want to include js file path rather I need to download js programmatically by jquery. like i will download js file programmatically from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js and check if the file can not be download or does not exist then i will download the same file from my site like www.my-site.com/js/1.5.2/jquery.min.js.

please help me to do it using jquery.

Comment: Why not just download it from google all the time? And how can we help you with jquery if jquery hasn't been downloaded yet?

Comment: You want to download jquery using jquery? You would have to download jquery first :)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you're trying to load jquery in the first place you will have to use plain old javascript to load the files until jquery has been loaded.  You could probably do this using standard XHR and injecting the file contents into a script tag.  Is there a reason you want to favor google's reference vs your own?  Edit: jquery recursive dependency already mentioned above :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to add script programmetically.
This following mechanism allows the rendering engine to immediately render and display the initial view  defined in HTML while the JavaScript resources are still being loaded and executed which leads to better user experience

```
      function loadScript(src, callback) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');
    done = false;
    script.setAttribute('src', src);
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');
    script.onload = script.onreadstatechange = function() {
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
            done = true;
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            }
    }
    head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
}

// load the my-script-file.js and display an alert dialog once the script has been loaded
loadScript('my-script-file.js', function() { ///Loaded, add your javascript here. });
```

When  tags are found in the HTML document the referenced script resources are downloaded and executed before the rendering engine can continue to download other resources which effectively blocks the rendering of the page below the tag. To avoid this blocking behaviour a script tag can be created via a mechanism known as a dynamic script tag injection  Reference(http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/)

Comment: "better user experience" compared to what?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script> this manual jquery include and programmetically adding script.

Comment: Or, you know, you could just include the JS at the *end* of the HTML, like everyone else does, instead of using this ridiculous hack.

Comment: I don't see how this will make a blind bit of difference to the "user experience".

Comment: When <script> tags are found in the HTML document the referenced script resources are downloaded and executed before the rendering engine can continue to download other resources which effectively blocks the rendering of the page below the tag. To avoid this blocking behaviour a script tag can be created via a mechanism known as a dynamic script tag injection  Reference(http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/)

Comment: @abdul: You cannot say, as a blanket statement, that this will hurt the "user experience". What if the script is _designed_ for that? Then your approach breaks the experience.

Comment: This is just community wiki, may be the user using old browsers.

Comment: @Tomalak: Google for "FOUC". It's a common pattern to avoid.

Comment: @Stefan: FOUC relates to CSS, not Javascript.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't think you understand the term. If a large file blocks the rendering of parts of the DOM or the inclusion of CSS, you get unstyled content, or no content at all.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't think that _you_ understand the term. It relates to CSS, not Javascript. No content at all is not a FOUC. Flashes of unstyled content -- which relates to CSS, not Javascript -- are FOUC.

Answer (score 3):

following code will solve your problem

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
       document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
 </script>
```